# Where are the Stack Exchange data dumps?

Tags: support, data-dump, faq-proposed

I see a lot of talk around here regarding the Stack Overflow public data dump.

Where is it? How can I play with it?

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/)

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/

Comment: @Popular Demand: Via above link, via http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/ and via http://media10.simplex.tv/content/xtendx/stu/stackoverflow/

Comment: FYI [How can I download the Stack Exchange data dump from archive.org through the command line?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306593/178179)

Answer (score 41):

The latest release of the data dump lives on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange).

A version of it (updated weekly) can be viewed and queried online at [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com) - the data here forms the basis for the quarterly data dump.

Older releases are [listed in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224922) - however, many are no longer available.

Comment: Is this updating still happens weekly? and is it on which day?

Comment: Yes, data.stackexchange.com gets updated weekly. Do you have a reason to think otherwise?

Comment: Thank you :) . I came across a post where it is mentioned this happens monthly and is obviously older than this. Since this post is older than one year, I was wondering whether it's changed. And which day is it?

Comment: See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156709/140505

Comment: @Oded which day of the week is the cutoff for being included? (Eg. if posted on Monday and deleted on Thursday, is it in?)

Comment: @DoubleAA - I've not worked at Stack Overflow for ~6 years now, no clue.

Answer (score 6):

Forage through the tag [**`[data-dump]`**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-dump) and read up a plenty while you sit back, relax and engorge yourself with cherry ripes and data dumps.

Related: [Better know a schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump/2678#2678).

And might be good to check out the blog at least once a month. Especially when they [squeeze out a good sized dump of the data](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/).