# Get the list of all my edits or counts of edits

Tags: feature-request, edits, personal-statistics

How do I get the list of all edits done by me or the counts of all edits done by me ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this currently.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a [list of your recent edits here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130243?tab=activity#sort-top), but there is no interface that will show you all your edits.  However, this information is in the [data dumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19579/where-is-stackoverflows-public-data-dump).