# When does Data Explorer get updated?

Tags: support, status-completed, data-explorer

... it looks like it's done in a monthly basis, but when does it usually get updated?
It's Aug 2nd and it still has data only up to June.

https://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: soon, usually a few hours after the data dump is made available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeff announces every time there's a new data dump on the SO blog, so you can watch for [those posts](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/). As far as I know waffles does the SEDE update manually, but it at least won't be before the data dump has been created

Comment: Thanks, I was about to ask where is the augusts data dump ;-)

Comment: @stacker: refer to this question -> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19579/where-is-stack-overflows-public-data-dump/63592#63592