# Stack Overflow XML data dump

Tags: support, stack-overflow, data-dump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is Stack Overflow's public data dump?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19579/where-is-stack-overflows-public-data-dump)

I was watching a "Tour of .NET 4.0" video by Scott Hanselman, and he mentioned that in one of his demonstration applications, he was using a freely available XML data dump from http://stackoverflow.com.

Where might a person find this data dump?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.clearbits.net/torrents/1419-sept-2010) at clearbits