# How do I get data streams from Stack Overflow to do data analysis?

Tags: discussion

I want to do some data analysis using Stack Overflow data. How can I stream data from Stack Overflow and then do some meaningful analysis on it?

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or download the most recent data dump. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19579/where-is-stack-overflows-public-data-dump

Answer (score 1):

You can live query all data on Stack Overflow by going [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new).

You can see some examples of what queries have been written [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries).