# Hosting all Stack Exchange data dumps on archive.org

Tags: discussion, data-dump, archive

Currently Stack Exchange only hosts the most recent dump on archive.org ([Where are the Stack Exchange data dumps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277952/178179)).

The previous dumps are only available through torrents: [All Stack Exchange data dumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224873/178179) (and nobody is seeding them: I unsuccessfully tried to download the dumps for 2016 December, 
2017 March, and 2017 June).

How about hosting all Stack Exchange data dumps on archive.org?

[image]

Comment: Except for when they refactor the database, I'm pretty sure that each is a superset of the previous.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 many questions and comments get deleted over time.

Comment: Don't they remain in the SQL data dump?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 regrettably, no

Comment: Well, you could just copy the dump to a separate item on archive.org once it gets out.

Comment: @Nemo that's why I did after asking this question, but I also would like to have access to past dumps.

Answer (score 15):

I encourage users to upload any old releases they have to the Internet Archive for safe keeping.

For example, [I have uploaded the first release to the Internet Archive here](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange-ea45080eab61ab465f647e6366f775bf25f69a61). If possible, include the associated torrent file, and include the files *as released* so they remain torrent-compatible. For example, [see my upload](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange-ea45080eab61ab465f647e6366f775bf25f69a61/May%202009%20Stack%20Exchange%20Data%20Dump/). Be sure to set the original release date and license information (Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike).

Once uploaded, we can edit them in to [the list of past releases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224873/all-stack-exchange-data-dumps/224922#224922) so they can be found.