# Seeking Stack Overflow data dump from 2012 to 2016

Tags: discussion, data-dump

From this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224922) to [All Stack Exchange data dumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224873/215590), the historical versions of Stack Overflow data dump are provided. However, from 2012 to 2016, it seems that the data dumps are not available.

Has anyone saved these data dumps that can share them online?

Comment: Given that it's an overall Stack Exchange data dump, and the links to it are in a post here on this site, this seems on-topic to me here and so I'm moving to leave this open.

Comment: Iirc, the latest data dump contains all the historical data. You could just download it and filter it by date as needed. I did that for a project I did.

Comment: You can view our [20 SE sites, 10 years ago](https://web.archive.org/web/20100815040625/http://stackexchange.com/sites) on Wayback. There are [various versions of this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306316/hosting-all-stack-exchange-data-dumps-on-archive-org?noredirect=1&lq=1) already - there are torrents but they are poorly seeded.