# Split the community and Community User statistics in "Year in Moderation" posts

Tags: feature-request, moderation, statistics, community-user, community

In the annual statistics posted on Meta Stack Exchange (e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341369/336163)) as well as each per-site Meta, moderation actions are aggregated into "Moderators" and "Community" columns, with the second caveated with,

> "Community" here refers both to the membership of [Site] without diamonds next to their names, and to the automated systems otherwise known as user #-1.

The very fact that a caveat is needed indicates the likelihood of confusion here, and I've never truly understood why these two concepts needed to be aggregated. What we do as a community is actually very different from the automated processes, which have been built by the developers and operate whether or not the community wills or has even considered the applicable action.

*Let's split the "Community" column in "Year of Moderation" posts to separate actions performed by ordinary users from automated actions performed by the system.*

The new report could look something like this:

```
                  Action                  Moderators Community    System
----------------------------------------- ---------- -------------------
Bases loaded                                     532       205         1
Splines reticulated                            1,003         3        44
Bars fooed                                         9        87     3,300
Acts of Mopery thwarted                            6         0         0
Planets vaporized                                 55         3         0
```

Comment: What about all the actions that Community performs as a direct result of member actions? The majority of things it does are because someone told it to do so. Separating the stats is probably going to be a *lot* less useful than you're anticipating.