# Will yearly moderation statistics be published on all sites this year, and future years?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderation, per-site-meta, statistics

For the last couple years, at the beginning of every new year, Stack Exchange has posted annual moderation statistics on all meta sites in the network. These posts include a full table on how many of which moderation actions were taken by the community and site moderators across all categories of moderation (e.g. review tasks reviewed, posts curated, users suspended/deleted, etc.) on the main site.

This [originally started in 2016 on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340815/2016-a-year-in-moderation), but since 2018, has included all sites in the network. As examples, here are last year's statistics for my top five sites:

- Meta Stack Exchange: [2019: a year in moderation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341369/2019-a-year-in-moderation)
- Travel: [2019: a year in moderation on Travel.SE](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/2019-a-year-in-moderation-on-travel-se)
- Stack Overflow: [2019: a year in moderation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392550/2019-a-year-in-moderation)
- Super User: [2019: a year in moderation](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13925/2019-a-year-in-moderation)
- Interpersonal Skills: [2019: a year in moderation](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3946/2019-a-year-in-moderation)

These were posted by Shog9 in previous years, but as he's no longer an SE employee, will another employee take the responsibility of posting these moderation stats tables on all SE sites?

Also, slightly related: will the annual [year in closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing) posts continue to be made here on this site? Those are tables showing statistics on closed questions on all network sites, posted here on this site.

Comment: I hope, it is interesting ;)

Comment: Generic answer to all questions starting of type "Will ... ?": Maybe.

Comment: It's not only just interesting, it's essential for regulars to see those stats as they give a view into how healthy their site is and which parts need work. There aren't many tools available for this (the 10k+ tools aren't enough on their own) and it would be a shame to go without these statistics.

Comment: Slightly off topic but, if this is to continue, could the combined moderator+automated statistics be separated next time?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We agree that the data exposed in the “year in moderation” posts that Shog9 made annually were very useful for site moderators and content curators. We have therefore spent some time reviewing the scripts created by Shog9 used for making these posts and making the changes needed to keep them running. I am happy to report that the current plan is to get these up sometime in the next few weeks.

Additionally, we see great value in having this data available and refreshed on a more frequent basis (and to do so in a way that doesn’t require as many manual steps). On that note, we are hoping to add roadmap item(s) in the future to expose tools and reports that will make these types of statistics available to moderators and site users, and to do so on a real-time basis.

We do not have a date yet for when this may take place, nor do we know right now what stats might be included, or whether or not it would be gated by a specific rep threshold. We will try to preview this to the Community and solicit more specific feedback when it is relevant to do so.

As far as an overall “year in closing” post for 2020, <s>we hope to post something similar in January</s> that [has been posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359735/2020-a-year-in-closing).

Comment: Can we get those up on January 1 next year, as they used to be published on that exact day on previous years?

Comment: @sonic in case it wasn't clear, this is probably the Iast year where we will be making these posts. But if we are going to post them again, they probably will not be posted on Jan 1 as this is always a company holiday.

Comment: Okay, if they are to still be published, can we please have them published on the first business day after January 1? (I might add that the previous years' posts were still published on January 1 despite that being a holiday.)

Comment: @sonic I can't make any commitments about this

Comment: Also well - mods don't really stop modding until they stop - so too soon in the new year will not be great

Comment: @sonic - please just chill. You demanding for this stuff to be done immediately, on your schedule is... kinda over the top. Shog did these posts on his own over the break and that was really cool of him but, to be completely honest, there is zero reason that anyone needs to see the content immediately after the year ends. Yes, it's good to have it in the first week or two but, first day back as a priority - that's really a bit much to demand.

Comment: Good to hear you're thinking about this! Wanna point out a couple things: (1) this was scripted so that I *didn't* have to spend a holiday writing posts; (2) real-time reports would be great, but a lot of this info was already available in bits and pieces - getting it to calculate for extended periods of time is what gave it value, so be careful not to lose that.

Comment: @shog there are things that changed in our infrastructure over the last year that required us to rewrite how parts of the script works. And any real time stuff we would plan for would hopefully also include showing values for different periods of time, including extended. Thanks

Comment: That happens constantly, @yaakov; I maintained those queries because I used them daily, but of course they're broken after a year of neglect. My point was that it wasn't a company holiday that prevented them from running on the 1st; they were explicitly designed to be run while their author was drinking eggnog and catching up on sleep!

Answer (score 22):

Make this happen. Please.

The users, super users, and moderators of each site will doubtless be interested in how their sites have performed this year.

Withholding these stats prevents users from understanding what needs to be improved in terms of question/answer quality.