# 2020: a year in closing

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, statistics, reopened-questions

I am thrilled to share that this year we are continuing a tradition started by [Shog9 five years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing). Please welcome stats that highlight how many questions were closed on different Stack Exchange sites in 2020:

| Site | Asked | Asked And Closed | Percent Asked And Closed | All Closed | Duplicates Closed | Duplicates Reopened | Off-Topic Closed | Off-Topic Reopened | Unclear Closed | Unclear Reopened | Too Broad Closed | Too Broad Reopened | Opinion Based Closed | Opinion Based Reopened |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Stack Overflow | 3,077,287 | 504,944 | 16.41% | 521,241 | 151,348 | 4,872 | 144,942 | 3,192 | 118,557 | 3,579 | 86,831 | 1,746 | 19,563 | 277 |
| Super User | 51,316 | 9,415 | 18.35% | 9,660 | 1,189 | 36 | 5,065 | 82 | 2,239 | 93 | 677 | 16 | 490 | 4 |
| Server Fault | 26,301 | 4,064 | 15.45% | 4,322 | 285 | 6 | 2,982 | 15 | 769 | 6 | 209 | 1 | 77 | 2 |
| Stack Apps | 204 | 26 | 12.75% | 26 | 1 | 0 | 23 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Seasoned Advice | 2,340 | 510 | 21.79% | 527 | 210 | 4 | 145 | 5 | 69 | 5 | 31 | 2 | 72 | 4 |
| Home Improvement | 10,754 | 857 | 7.97% | 1,016 | 106 | 4 | 457 | 5 | 310 | 6 | 79 | 2 | 64 | 1 |
| Game Development | 5,326 | 797 | 14.96% | 876 | 150 | 7 | 461 | 21 | 80 | 3 | 106 | 3 | 79 | 5 |
| Arqade | 6,795 | 1,848 | 27.2% | 2,109 | 765 | 13 | 604 | 13 | 601 | 19 | 72 | 6 | 67 | 4 |
| Geographic Information Systems | 19,727 | 3,788 | 19.2% | 4,090 | 591 | 28 | 1,602 | 89 | 1,052 | 90 | 616 | 96 | 229 | 9 |
| Photography | 1,737 | 330 | 19.0% | 344 | 92 | 0 | 165 | 2 | 60 | 2 | 4 | 0 | 23 | 1 |
| Statistical Analysis | 36,765 | 7,111 | 19.34% | 7,553 | 1,419 | 36 | 3,109 | 94 | 2,557 | 239 | 404 | 29 | 64 | 4 |
| Web Applications | 4,757 | 675 | 14.19% | 719 | 130 | 0 | 390 | 2 | 174 | 7 | 17 | 0 | 8 | 0 |
| Pro Webmasters | 3,226 | 1,318 | 40.86% | 1,374 | 227 | 5 | 617 | 11 | 302 | 53 | 162 | 13 | 66 | 4 |
| Apple | 14,341 | 2,108 | 14.7% | 2,235 | 863 | 38 | 604 | 54 | 556 | 102 | 101 | 34 | 111 | 10 |
| Theoretical Computer Science | 1,323 | 331 | 25.02% | 335 | 5 | 0 | 304 | 0 | 14 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| English Language & Usage | 15,862 | 6,245 | 39.37% | 6,534 | 1,214 | 23 | 3,975 | 44 | 673 | 15 | 74 | 2 | 598 | 11 |
| Personal Finance & Money | 5,665 | 1,161 | 20.49% | 1,200 | 228 | 2 | 635 | 12 | 133 | 3 | 77 | 1 | 127 | 5 |
| Role-playing Games | 5,195 | 1,339 | 25.77% | 1,437 | 485 | 100 | 191 | 24 | 420 | 172 | 130 | 40 | 211 | 38 |
| TeX - LaTeX | 25,865 | 2,828 | 10.93% | 3,151 | 1,469 | 52 | 743 | 9 | 802 | 23 | 80 | 4 | 57 | 2 |
| Ask Ubuntu | 56,898 | 10,134 | 17.81% | 11,225 | 4,955 | 57 | 3,988 | 94 | 1,785 | 44 | 189 | 5 | 308 | 6 |
| Unix & Linux | 30,855 | 3,169 | 10.27% | 3,297 | 1,187 | 38 | 740 | 5 | 966 | 21 | 196 | 4 | 208 | 1 |
| WordPress | 14,793 | 2,692 | 18.2% | 2,824 | 91 | 0 | 2,425 | 13 | 173 | 3 | 94 | 1 | 41 | 2 |
| Bicycles | 2,429 | 273 | 11.24% | 288 | 110 | 0 | 125 | 4 | 42 | 1 | 7 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Software Engineering | 7,039 | 2,029 | 28.83% | 2,048 | 85 | 4 | 1,253 | 5 | 195 | 3 | 351 | 1 | 164 | 3 |
| Android Enthusiasts | 6,131 | 1,504 | 24.53% | 1,595 | 321 | 11 | 963 | 23 | 259 | 17 | 40 | 2 | 12 | 1 |
| Board & Card Games | 1,118 | 223 | 19.95% | 231 | 92 | 9 | 48 | 7 | 37 | 3 | 20 | 5 | 34 | 5 |
| Physics | 37,368 | 11,428 | 30.58% | 11,773 | 2,087 | 50 | 6,687 | 49 | 2,075 | 63 | 539 | 27 | 385 | 10 |
| Homebrewing | 253 | 3 | 1.19% | 3 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Information Security | 8,645 | 3,335 | 38.58% | 3,405 | 507 | 9 | 2,002 | 22 | 518 | 14 | 213 | 11 | 165 | 4 |
| Writing | 1,573 | 510 | 32.42% | 522 | 69 | 0 | 354 | 2 | 34 | 0 | 21 | 0 | 44 | 0 |
| Electrical Engineering | 28,335 | 4,188 | 14.78% | 4,295 | 377 | 4 | 2,150 | 44 | 1,021 | 32 | 579 | 9 | 168 | 3 |
| Graphic Design | 3,970 | 647 | 16.3% | 664 | 124 | 4 | 284 | 2 | 104 | 1 | 114 | 0 | 38 | 0 |
| Database Administrators | 11,547 | 2,447 | 21.19% | 2,763 | 345 | 10 | 1,096 | 11 | 885 | 25 | 328 | 8 | 109 | 1 |
| Science Fiction & Fantasy | 5,614 | 1,349 | 24.03% | 1,497 | 668 | 36 | 348 | 35 | 174 | 32 | 101 | 19 | 206 | 27 |
| Area 51 Discussions | 234 | 11 | 4.7% | 11 | 3 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Code Review | 9,203 | 2,145 | 23.31% | 2,172 | 18 | 1 | 1,961 | 33 | 181 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 9 | 0 |
| Code Golf | 1,234 | 427 | 34.6% | 474 | 75 | 13 | 214 | 3 | 180 | 28 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Quantitative Finance | 4,231 | 639 | 15.1% | 651 | 65 | 0 | 326 | 2 | 152 | 4 | 53 | 0 | 55 | 0 |
| Project Management | 613 | 133 | 21.7% | 141 | 4 | 0 | 68 | 1 | 31 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 32 | 1 |
| Skeptics | 1,115 | 451 | 40.45% | 456 | 34 | 2 | 294 | 34 | 68 | 25 | 36 | 8 | 24 | 3 |
| Drupal Answers | 5,345 | 1,082 | 20.24% | 1,287 | 188 | 3 | 337 | 5 | 510 | 12 | 200 | 3 | 52 | 3 |
| Physical Fitness | 789 | 220 | 27.88% | 231 | 20 | 1 | 170 | 8 | 19 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 14 | 1 |
| Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair | 2,460 | 313 | 12.72% | 322 | 45 | 0 | 148 | 4 | 87 | 0 | 9 | 0 | 33 | 1 |
| Parenting | 448 | 118 | 26.34% | 122 | 10 | 0 | 58 | 4 | 25 | 0 | 10 | 1 | 19 | 1 |
| SharePoint | 6,748 | 400 | 5.93% | 404 | 47 | 0 | 90 | 1 | 209 | 13 | 44 | 4 | 14 | 0 |
| Music: Practice & Theory | 3,635 | 829 | 22.81% | 939 | 206 | 5 | 391 | 9 | 127 | 7 | 66 | 2 | 149 | 1 |
| Software Quality Assurance & Testing | 1,393 | 356 | 25.56% | 403 | 58 | 1 | 74 | 1 | 196 | 9 | 35 | 1 | 40 | 0 |
| Mi Yodeya | 2,871 | 692 | 24.1% | 733 | 250 | 1 | 291 | 15 | 121 | 13 | 36 | 4 | 35 | 2 |
| Astronomy | 2,278 | 357 | 15.67% | 373 | 150 | 1 | 128 | 15 | 54 | 1 | 20 | 1 | 21 | 0 |
| German Language | 1,507 | 358 | 23.76% | 371 | 109 | 6 | 185 | 23 | 53 | 9 | 8 | 1 | 16 | 1 |
| Japanese Language | 3,292 | 744 | 22.6% | 753 | 325 | 12 | 366 | 7 | 37 | 3 | 8 | 1 | 17 | 1 |
| Gardening & Landscaping | 2,225 | 60 | 2.7% | 65 | 6 | 0 | 17 | 1 | 32 | 6 | 7 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| Philosophy | 2,675 | 740 | 27.66% | 755 | 72 | 0 | 347 | 1 | 175 | 5 | 56 | 0 | 105 | 1 |
| Travel | 3,269 | 1,216 | 37.2% | 1,277 | 368 | 19 | 509 | 51 | 184 | 30 | 46 | 6 | 170 | 22 |
| Cryptography | 4,117 | 838 | 20.35% | 863 | 125 | 5 | 587 | 12 | 82 | 2 | 45 | 1 | 24 | 0 |
| Literature | 1,340 | 148 | 11.04% | 149 | 9 | 0 | 88 | 8 | 25 | 1 | 18 | 1 | 9 | 1 |
| Signal Processing | 4,273 | 461 | 10.79% | 465 | 69 | 1 | 194 | 3 | 116 | 3 | 78 | 4 | 8 | 1 |
| French Language | 1,111 | 120 | 10.8% | 123 | 54 | 2 | 53 | 1 | 9 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Christianity | 1,401 | 593 | 42.33% | 648 | 70 | 10 | 339 | 22 | 82 | 9 | 55 | 4 | 102 | 5 |
| Bitcoin | 3,074 | 821 | 26.71% | 998 | 193 | 3 | 614 | 3 | 105 | 6 | 32 | 2 | 54 | 0 |
| Linguistics | 1,566 | 413 | 26.37% | 423 | 18 | 0 | 271 | 7 | 78 | 0 | 31 | 0 | 25 | 1 |
| Biblical Hermeneutics | 2,012 | 376 | 18.69% | 389 | 57 | 4 | 204 | 11 | 59 | 2 | 17 | 3 | 52 | 6 |
| Economics | 3,427 | 793 | 23.14% | 804 | 52 | 2 | 403 | 7 | 172 | 0 | 75 | 0 | 102 | 0 |
| History | 2,325 | 895 | 38.49% | 921 | 39 | 2 | 475 | 18 | 163 | 9 | 109 | 6 | 135 | 6 |
| Bricks | 611 | 76 | 12.44% | 81 | 33 | 0 | 9 | 0 | 32 | 2 | 4 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| Spanish Language | 915 | 118 | 12.9% | 126 | 44 | 0 | 60 | 2 | 13 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| Computational Science | 1,412 | 166 | 11.76% | 170 | 5 | 0 | 110 | 2 | 41 | 1 | 7 | 0 | 7 | 0 |
| Movies & TV | 2,409 | 755 | 31.34% | 768 | 62 | 1 | 425 | 10 | 122 | 11 | 55 | 5 | 104 | 6 |
| Chinese Language | 1,489 | 143 | 9.6% | 217 | 50 | 2 | 100 | 2 | 28 | 2 | 12 | 0 | 27 | 1 |
| Biology | 4,166 | 1,121 | 26.91% | 1,156 | 111 | 4 | 602 | 21 | 187 | 5 | 65 | 3 | 191 | 3 |
| Poker | 165 | 32 | 19.39% | 33 | 26 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Mathematica | 10,840 | 2,059 | 18.99% | 2,143 | 384 | 12 | 1,441 | 19 | 285 | 9 | 22 | 0 | 11 | 1 |
| Psychology & Neuroscience | 1,144 | 370 | 32.34% | 382 | 25 | 0 | 223 | 5 | 55 | 0 | 29 | 0 | 50 | 1 |
| The Great Outdoors | 341 | 31 | 9.09% | 32 | 6 | 0 | 20 | 2 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Martial Arts | 222 | 28 | 12.61% | 33 | 8 | 0 | 12 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 6 | 1 | 4 | 0 |
| Sports | 460 | 149 | 32.39% | 156 | 22 | 0 | 68 | 3 | 28 | 3 | 12 | 1 | 26 | 3 |
| Academia | 5,710 | 2,122 | 37.16% | 2,191 | 413 | 5 | 1,420 | 20 | 139 | 5 | 65 | 2 | 154 | 10 |
| Computer Science | 7,792 | 1,077 | 13.82% | 1,099 | 175 | 5 | 628 | 6 | 214 | 12 | 68 | 1 | 14 | 0 |
| The Workplace | 3,802 | 959 | 25.22% | 962 | 132 | 20 | 560 | 38 | 83 | 5 | 71 | 5 | 116 | 11 |
| Windows Phone | 31 | 7 | 22.58% | 8 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Chemistry | 9,575 | 5,181 | 54.11% | 5,242 | 513 | 8 | 2,690 | 71 | 1,559 | 70 | 375 | 21 | 105 | 2 |
| Chess | 1,383 | 221 | 15.98% | 230 | 72 | 5 | 59 | 1 | 23 | 6 | 20 | 5 | 56 | 2 |
| Raspberry Pi | 5,277 | 871 | 16.51% | 928 | 95 | 2 | 447 | 6 | 254 | 19 | 67 | 4 | 65 | 1 |
| Russian Language | 364 | 111 | 30.49% | 113 | 12 | 2 | 68 | 3 | 25 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 6 | 1 |
| Islam | 2,832 | 726 | 25.64% | 753 | 236 | 2 | 226 | 1 | 157 | 2 | 39 | 0 | 95 | 1 |
| Salesforce | 19,878 | 3,690 | 18.56% | 3,741 | 903 | 20 | 1,770 | 24 | 845 | 7 | 100 | 2 | 123 | 3 |
| Ask Patents | 398 | 14 | 3.52% | 14 | 3 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| User Experience | 2,084 | 481 | 23.08% | 505 | 30 | 0 | 248 | 0 | 92 | 1 | 34 | 2 | 101 | 0 |
| Genealogy & Family History | 358 | 61 | 17.04% | 63 | 26 | 0 | 10 | 1 | 20 | 3 | 4 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| Robotics | 923 | 150 | 16.25% | 153 | 1 | 0 | 49 | 1 | 37 | 3 | 17 | 0 | 49 | 1 |
| Politics | 3,309 | 1,273 | 38.47% | 1,313 | 180 | 11 | 613 | 105 | 175 | 20 | 108 | 26 | 237 | 46 |
| Video Production | 1,483 | 121 | 8.16% | 122 | 16 | 0 | 67 | 0 | 19 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 14 | 0 |
| Anime & Manga | 1,274 | 457 | 35.87% | 467 | 55 | 0 | 303 | 0 | 49 | 2 | 12 | 2 | 48 | 0 |
| Magento | 14,727 | 412 | 2.8% | 430 | 49 | 0 | 99 | 0 | 241 | 6 | 20 | 0 | 21 | 1 |
| English Language Learners | 15,559 | 1,709 | 10.98% | 1,797 | 402 | 7 | 1,047 | 29 | 226 | 7 | 68 | 1 | 54 | 0 |
| Sustainable Living | 234 | 27 | 11.54% | 36 | 0 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 21 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Tridion | 363 | 5 | 1.38% | 5 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Reverse Engineering | 1,544 | 132 | 8.55% | 136 | 7 | 1 | 55 | 0 | 60 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 10 | 0 |
| Arduino | 4,214 | 819 | 19.44% | 830 | 135 | 1 | 280 | 1 | 279 | 9 | 111 | 4 | 25 | 0 |
| Network Engineering | 4,024 | 2,629 | 65.33% | 2,673 | 160 | 0 | 2,072 | 9 | 264 | 17 | 136 | 5 | 41 | 1 |
| Open Data | 733 | 35 | 4.77% | 44 | 18 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 12 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Freelancing | 162 | 31 | 19.14% | 32 | 3 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Blender | 24,741 | 3,936 | 15.91% | 4,086 | 2,258 | 84 | 455 | 8 | 961 | 98 | 223 | 23 | 189 | 6 |
| MathOverflow | 17,911 | 3,375 | 18.84% | 3,396 | 65 | 2 | 3,053 | 20 | 208 | 1 | 45 | 2 | 25 | 1 |
| Space Exploration | 2,719 | 319 | 11.73% | 324 | 89 | 1 | 113 | 16 | 48 | 3 | 40 | 2 | 34 | 4 |
| Sound Design | 768 | 241 | 31.38% | 251 | 13 | 0 | 193 | 0 | 20 | 1 | 8 | 0 | 17 | 0 |
| Tor | 573 | 19 | 3.32% | 27 | 6 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 17 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| Pets | 973 | 153 | 15.72% | 162 | 108 | 2 | 20 | 1 | 25 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Amateur Radio | 657 | 76 | 11.57% | 78 | 11 | 1 | 36 | 0 | 19 | 6 | 7 | 2 | 5 | 1 |
| Italian Language | 422 | 25 | 5.92% | 26 | 5 | 0 | 15 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Stack Overflow em Português | 36,571 | 18,150 | 49.63% | 19,074 | 978 | 35 | 13,374 | 178 | 3,842 | 83 | 748 | 9 | 132 | 1 |
| Aviation | 3,290 | 891 | 27.08% | 919 | 279 | 11 | 277 | 3 | 169 | 12 | 84 | 4 | 110 | 7 |
| Ebooks | 157 | 11 | 7.01% | 11 | 1 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Beer, Wine & Spirits | 94 | 13 | 13.83% | 15 | 3 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Software Recommendations | 3,097 | 390 | 12.59% | 410 | 10 | 0 | 318 | 14 | 76 | 10 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| CS50 | 2,448 | 20 | 0.82% | 22 | 9 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Expatriates | 932 | 80 | 8.58% | 88 | 25 | 1 | 21 | 0 | 16 | 1 | 7 | 0 | 19 | 0 |
| Mathematics Educators | 448 | 92 | 20.54% | 93 | 4 | 0 | 59 | 0 | 14 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 10 | 0 |
| Earth Science | 800 | 178 | 22.25% | 188 | 27 | 1 | 95 | 5 | 40 | 1 | 20 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| Joomla | 584 | 26 | 4.45% | 34 | 5 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 19 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Data Science | 10,555 | 2,193 | 20.78% | 2,428 | 81 | 2 | 945 | 6 | 850 | 14 | 405 | 8 | 147 | 1 |
| Puzzling | 4,045 | 566 | 13.99% | 575 | 121 | 5 | 378 | 38 | 55 | 7 | 13 | 2 | 8 | 0 |
| Craft CMS | 1,380 | 10 | 0.72% | 11 | 5 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Buddhism | 895 | 86 | 9.61% | 90 | 25 | 5 | 44 | 7 | 10 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 7 | 1 |
| Hinduism | 2,062 | 481 | 23.33% | 499 | 215 | 4 | 141 | 5 | 38 | 0 | 22 | 1 | 83 | 2 |
| Community Building | 44 | 7 | 15.91% | 7 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Worldbuilding | 5,368 | 1,765 | 32.88% | 1,825 | 195 | 18 | 682 | 39 | 298 | 33 | 346 | 34 | 304 | 15 |
| スタック・オーバーフロー (Japanese) | 5,563 | 239 | 4.3% | 246 | 23 | 0 | 122 | 9 | 86 | 1 | 7 | 0 | 8 | 0 |
| Emacs | 3,548 | 54 | 1.52% | 60 | 36 | 1 | 10 | 1 | 7 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| History of Science & Mathematics | 639 | 91 | 14.24% | 91 | 16 | 0 | 36 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 10 | 1 | 18 | 1 |
| Lifehacks | 340 | 124 | 36.47% | 129 | 18 | 0 | 109 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Engineering | 2,990 | 494 | 16.52% | 504 | 21 | 1 | 113 | 2 | 263 | 18 | 66 | 0 | 41 | 0 |
| Coffee | 149 | 6 | 4.03% | 7 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Vi and Vim | 2,419 | 176 | 7.28% | 186 | 126 | 2 | 25 | 1 | 27 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 5 | 2 |
| Music Fans | 645 | 79 | 12.25% | 107 | 10 | 0 | 74 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 7 | 1 | 11 | 0 |
| Woodworking | 505 | 39 | 7.72% | 40 | 4 | 0 | 27 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| CiviCRM | 1,619 | 14 | 0.86% | 17 | 10 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Medical Sciences | 2,260 | 990 | 43.81% | 1,062 | 38 | 0 | 835 | 34 | 70 | 3 | 22 | 2 | 97 | 6 |
| Stack Overflow на русском | 90,134 | 10,811 | 11.99% | 11,013 | 1,843 | 37 | 4,715 | 93 | 2,787 | 47 | 727 | 19 | 941 | 6 |
| Русский язык | 1,712 | 231 | 13.49% | 236 | 19 | 0 | 162 | 3 | 27 | 1 | 17 | 2 | 11 | 1 |
| Mythology | 209 | 16 | 7.66% | 16 | 5 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Law | 4,892 | 757 | 15.47% | 774 | 122 | 8 | 436 | 26 | 132 | 9 | 50 | 4 | 34 | 1 |
| Open Source | 858 | 157 | 18.3% | 163 | 57 | 3 | 79 | 4 | 18 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| elementary OS | 1,821 | 49 | 2.69% | 54 | 26 | 1 | 13 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| Portuguese Language | 326 | 31 | 9.51% | 31 | 8 | 0 | 19 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Computer Graphics | 630 | 24 | 3.81% | 25 | 0 | 0 | 19 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| Hardware Recommendations | 1,132 | 598 | 52.83% | 626 | 2 | 0 | 564 | 10 | 32 | 6 | 22 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| Stack Overflow en español | 53,971 | 5,735 | 10.63% | 5,951 | 673 | 13 | 2,137 | 53 | 1,483 | 26 | 565 | 9 | 1,093 | 12 |
| 3D Printing | 1,122 | 139 | 12.39% | 144 | 26 | 1 | 43 | 1 | 58 | 9 | 6 | 1 | 11 | 1 |
| Ethereum | 5,548 | 957 | 17.25% | 996 | 146 | 0 | 243 | 3 | 431 | 2 | 146 | 1 | 30 | 0 |
| Latin Language | 791 | 23 | 2.91% | 24 | 6 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Language Learning | 302 | 125 | 41.39% | 127 | 2 | 0 | 103 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 10 | 1 | 7 | 0 |
| Retrocomputing | 1,200 | 191 | 15.92% | 193 | 14 | 1 | 94 | 8 | 31 | 4 | 24 | 6 | 30 | 1 |
| Arts & Crafts | 344 | 94 | 27.33% | 96 | 9 | 0 | 45 | 2 | 25 | 0 | 10 | 1 | 7 | 1 |
| Korean Language | 264 | 16 | 6.06% | 16 | 4 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 7 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Monero | 353 | 29 | 8.22% | 30 | 26 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Artificial Intelligence | 3,913 | 608 | 15.54% | 831 | 67 | 3 | 380 | 21 | 213 | 47 | 101 | 22 | 70 | 7 |
| Esperanto Language | 163 | 5 | 3.07% | 5 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Sitecore | 1,970 | 404 | 20.51% | 414 | 97 | 2 | 126 | 4 | 127 | 13 | 51 | 3 | 13 | 0 |
| Internet of Things | 372 | 88 | 23.66% | 88 | 6 | 0 | 25 | 0 | 40 | 0 | 15 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Vegetarianism | 64 | 13 | 20.31% | 16 | 3 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Ukrainian Language | 108 | 6 | 5.56% | 6 | 1 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| DevOps | 1,516 | 88 | 5.8% | 90 | 8 | 0 | 41 | 0 | 25 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 8 | 0 |
| Bioinformatics | 1,490 | 129 | 8.66% | 131 | 7 | 0 | 31 | 1 | 61 | 2 | 23 | 0 | 9 | 0 |
| Computer Science Educators | 186 | 49 | 26.34% | 50 | 4 | 1 | 41 | 0 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Interpersonal Skills | 730 | 369 | 50.55% | 370 | 15 | 0 | 163 | 2 | 104 | 4 | 23 | 1 | 65 | 5 |
| Iota | 56 | 3 | 5.36% | 3 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Stellar | 273 | 22 | 8.06% | 22 | 2 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| Constructed Languages | 85 | 14 | 16.47% | 14 | 3 | 0 | 7 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Quantum Computing | 2,292 | 221 | 9.64% | 225 | 55 | 0 | 35 | 2 | 81 | 1 | 31 | 2 | 23 | 1 |
| EOS.IO | 283 | 19 | 6.71% | 20 | 5 | 0 | 10 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Tezos | 552 | 47 | 8.51% | 51 | 16 | 0 | 22 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Operations Research | 977 | 40 | 4.09% | 40 | 11 | 0 | 14 | 2 | 10 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Drones and Model Aircraft | 511 | 39 | 7.63% | 39 | 6 | 0 | 12 | 2 | 9 | 2 | 9 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| Matter Modeling | 973 | 73 | 7.5% | 73 | 5 | 1 | 23 | 7 | 31 | 3 | 11 | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| Mathematics | 238,392 | 41,918 | 17.58% | 44,468 | 101,41 | 240 | 20,680 | 333 | 12,600 | 239 | 642 | 17 | 405 | 1 |

#### Notes

- This counts questions asked in 2020 and questions closed in 2020 - the AskedAndClosed and PctAskedAndClosed columns reflect questions that were *both* asked and closed in 2020, while the remaining columns total up all questions closed in 2020 - even those asked in prior years.
- Reopen numbers also include questions asked in years prior - but limit themselves to questions that were closed in 2020 and then also reopened in 2020.
- If a question was closed twice, it'll be counted twice.
- If a question was reopened twice, it'll be counted twice.

### Alternate formats

- CSV: https://gist.github.com/chabanovsky/19afa84f300e1929a826fe561657b666

Comment: please consider [edit]ing to clarify whether deleted questions are taken into account or not

Comment: @gnat It is all questions, including deleted ones.

Comment: Can the table be sortable by column?

Comment: +1 for sortable .. or at least sorting them alphabetically ;) if that's not an option.

Comment: @bad_coder: [status-deferred](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357021/369802). This has turned out to be one very, very long table though... @ Nicolas Last year, the information was also provided [as a CSV](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341507/369802), could that be an option this year too for those that want to sort?

Comment: By the power of LibreOffice, the csv https://gist.github.com/braiam/a791c0932f777dbd12c69d1e53cedb4b

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Yes, it seems there is now way to sort by column currently. I updated the question. Thank you!

Comment: Will the per-site detailed stats be updated too? (A year in moderation?)

Comment: @Braiam Good question! Yes, those posts will be out soon...

Comment: The last seven columns are not visible, no matter the zoom level (though there are plenty of pixels on the screen to show it). The GitHub page has the same problem. Firefox 84.0.2.

Comment: @P.Mort. There's a scrollbar at the bottom of the table that lets you see them.

Comment: @TylerH But the table has the usual SO/SE problem that the vertical scrolling window can be taller than the screen, so you have to move down the screen, blindly scroll the window horizontally as far as maybe you wanted, then blindly scroll back up the screen to maybe the line you were at.

Comment: @philipxy Yes, I didn't say there was no problem at all with the layout (I agree with you there are some big problems--personally I think table support should include the abilty to have sticky/frozen headers, at the very least). Btw, you can also scroll left and right by single-clicking anywhere on the table and using the directional left- and right-arrow keys.

Comment: _IT Security_  – It's called "Information Security" now and has been for a while.

Comment: By the way, where did the names of the sites come from? A lot of these names are old names of sites whose names have since been revised or completely changed (e.g. "Cognitive Sciences", "LEGO", and "Materials Modeling"). Also, it's missing data for Mathematics.

Comment: There's an internal instance of SEDE that suffers from the same issue as the public instance, @sonic: it has its own sites table with metadata on the databases it has imported, including name, which is never really updated. To get the proper site names for data like this, one must query the actual `Sites` table used by the system itself, which is slightly less convenient than just choosing the "run on all sites" option and letting SEDE fill it in. You can observe this same effect in some of my old posts when I was in a hurry.

Comment: Do you have spam statistics too? It would be interesting to compare them against what we have in Charcoal's own database [metasmoke](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/graphs) (unfortunately, no 12-month view, though I guess we could scrape together something if there is interest).

Comment: @Shog9 There is no Sites table on the public SEDE, only in the archive.org dump. It would be trivial to make one, it was asked many times, nothing happened, as usual. But a two-page long CASE/WHEN, iterating over sysdatabases.dbname , can work.

Comment: Why were the line breaks in this post [saved as HTML entities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359760/revision-history-shows-all-the-text-changed-post-stored-as-one-long-line-with) instead of as actual line breaks? This resulted in malformed revision diffs for revisions up to 11 (in rendered output views) as the view thought a single long line was being edited instead of multiple different ones.

Comment: @Sonic Actually the problem is still present; I made a small experimental edit in rev 13 and it still displays a diff of the entire post.

Comment: Maybe sort the table by number of questions asked, that way one can compare larger stackexchanges more easily.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you for the notice. I took a look at Mathematics.SE separately and realised that my query threw an error for the site and it was silently skipped by the system. My colleagues helped me fix the error. The results for Mathematics.SE at the very bottom of the list.

Comment: @JohnOmielan This stats table has never included Meta.SE stats in the past. Shog posted a comment on the 2019 post explaining why.

Comment: There is one in the private version though, @peterh. Sites.dbo.Sites iirc; it is mildly annoying to join against, but guarantees accurate info in cases like this.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks! And a unified db, containing all the data, does not exist somewhere behind the https://stackexchange.com ? The site network looks as if the sites would be stand-alone entities but cross-site communication (like cross-site event history, cross-site suspensions and so) would happen over some IPC mechanism. This makes likely that the company actually *has* some unified DB behind, only mortals have no access even to the knowledge about its existence.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I made a feature request which hopes to solve that problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360150/391772. Feel free to add to it!

Answer (score 20):

Did you ever wonder how many Hot Network Questions end up being closed (because they turn out not to be suitable for the site, or to be a duplicate)? Since [March 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/324643/295232) that information is registered, so we can fire up the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) engines to find out. SEDE doesn't include information about deleted questions, but those should be rare among HNQs.

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1359583/of-hnqs-closed?year=2020) is a query which shows the results on the SEDE website (so you can sort the columns); [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1359733/of-hnqs-closed-markdown-table-output?year=2020&opt.textResults=true) is a version which produces the following table, sorted by percentage closed:

| Site | Number of HNQs | Number of HNQs closed | % of HNQs closed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [StackExchange.English](https://english.stackexchange.com) | 585 | 110 | 18 |
| [StackExchange.Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com) | 470 | 74 | 15 |
| [StackExchange.Devops](https://devops.stackexchange.com) | 7 | 1 | 14 |
| [StackExchange.Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com) | 1421 | 201 | 14 |
| [StackExchange.Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com) | 531 | 72 | 13 |
| [StackExchange.Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com) | 33 | 4 | 12 |
| [StackExchange.Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com) | 895 | 115 | 12 |
| [StackExchange.Cogsci](https://psychology.stackexchange.com) | 9 | 1 | 11 |
| [StackExchange.Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com) | 128 | 13 | 10 |
| [StackExchange.Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com) | 1504 | 159 | 10 |
| [StackExchange.Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com) | 599 | 63 | 10 |
| [StackExchange.Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) | 640 | 59 | 9 |
| [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) | 873 | 80 | 9 |
| [StackExchange.Musicfans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com) | 22 | 2 | 9 |
| [StackExchange.Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com) | 365 | 35 | 9 |
| [StackExchange.Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com) | 113 | 11 | 9 |
| [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com) | 243 | 23 | 9 |
| [StackExchange.Esperanto](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com) | 12 | 1 | 8 |
| [StackExchange.Interpersonal](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com) | 56 | 5 | 8 |
| [StackExchange.Health](https://health.stackexchange.com) | 84 | 6 | 7 |
| [StackExchange.Money](https://money.stackexchange.com) | 503 | 36 | 7 |
| [StackExchange.Music](https://music.stackexchange.com) | 792 | 58 | 7 |
| [StackExchange.Security](https://security.stackexchange.com) | 314 | 23 | 7 |
| [StackExchange.Sqa](https://sqa.stackexchange.com) | 69 | 5 | 7 |
| [StackExchange.Stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com) | 868 | 56 | 6 |
| [StackExchange.Garage](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com) | 121 | 8 | 6 |
| [StackExchange.Datascience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com) | 187 | 12 | 6 |
| [StackExchange.Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com) | 594 | 37 | 6 |
| [StackExchange.Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) | 1430 | 79 | 5 |
| [StackExchange.Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com) | 90 | 5 | 5 |
| [StackExchange.Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com) | 87 | 5 | 5 |
| [StackExchange.Math](https://math.stackexchange.com) | 3315 | 190 | 5 |
| [StackExchange.Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com) | 1642 | 87 | 5 |
| [StackExchange.Scifi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com) | 1288 | 76 | 5 |
| [StackExchange.Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) | 167 | 10 | 5 |
| [StackExchange.Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com) | 536 | 27 | 5 |
| [StackExchange.Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com) | 676 | 38 | 5 |
| [StackExchange.Vi](https://vi.stackexchange.com) | 334 | 17 | 5 |
| [StackExchange.WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) | 19 | 1 | 5 |
| [StackExchange.Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com) | 1060 | 63 | 5 |
| [StackExchange.Woodworking](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com) | 18 | 1 | 5 |
| [StackExchange.Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com) | 204 | 10 | 4 |
| [StackExchange.Opensource](https://opensource.stackexchange.com) | 146 | 7 | 4 |
| [StackExchange.Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com) | 71 | 3 | 4 |
| [StackExchange.Raspberrypi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com) | 128 | 6 | 4 |
| [StackExchange.History](https://history.stackexchange.com) | 313 | 13 | 4 |
| [StackExchange.Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com) | 324 | 16 | 4 |
| [StackExchange.German](https://german.stackexchange.com) | 239 | 10 | 4 |
| [StackExchange.Gis](https://gis.stackexchange.com) | 811 | 27 | 3 |
| [StackExchange.Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com) | 347 | 11 | 3 |
| [StackExchange.Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com) | 133 | 5 | 3 |
| [StackExchange.Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com) | 59 | 2 | 3 |
| [StackExchange.Hsm](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) | 55 | 2 | 3 |
| [StackExchange.Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net) | 1242 | 38 | 3 |
| [StackExchange.Pm](https://pm.stackexchange.com) | 97 | 3 | 3 |
| [StackExchange.Ux](https://ux.stackexchange.com) | 83 | 3 | 3 |
| [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) | 424 | 16 | 3 |
| [StackExchange.Writers](https://writing.stackexchange.com) | 170 | 5 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com) | 657 | 15 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com) | 147 | 4 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com) | 1927 | 45 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com) | 1642 | 34 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Quant](https://quant.stackexchange.com) | 239 | 5 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Quantumcomputing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com) | 232 | 5 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Matheducators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com) | 116 | 3 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com) | 190 | 4 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com) | 146 | 3 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com) | 97 | 2 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Martialarts](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com) | 38 | 1 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com) | 588 | 16 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com) | 1044 | 27 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Boardgames](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com) | 279 | 8 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.3dprinting](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com) | 47 | 1 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Ai](https://ai.stackexchange.com) | 131 | 3 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Graphicdesign](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) | 180 | 4 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com) | 327 | 9 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Ell](https://ell.stackexchange.com) | 548 | 12 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Diy](https://diy.stackexchange.com) | 1014 | 25 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Bioinformatics](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com) | 49 | 1 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com) | 348 | 10 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com) | 368 | 10 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com) | 121 | 3 | 2 |
| [StackExchange.Dsp](https://dsp.stackexchange.com) | 199 | 2 | 1 |
| [StackExchange.French](https://french.stackexchange.com) | 154 | 2 | 1 |
| [StackExchange.GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com) | 67 | 1 | 1 |
| [StackExchange.Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com) | 100 | 1 | 1 |
| [StackExchange.Fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com) | 77 | 1 | 1 |
| [StackExchange.Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com) | 505 | 9 | 1 |
| [StackExchange.Bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com) | 696 | 12 | 1 |
| [StackExchange.Bricks](https://bricks.stackexchange.com) | 217 | 3 | 1 |
| [StackExchange.Chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com) | 567 | 10 | 1 |
| [StackExchange.Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com) | 366 | 4 | 1 |
| [StackExchange.Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) | 914 | 15 | 1 |
| [StackExchange.Crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) | 324 | 6 | 1 |
| [StackExchange.Materials](https://materials.stackexchange.com) | 253 | 3 | 1 |
| [StackExchange.Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com) | 507 | 9 | 1 |
| [StackExchange.Law](https://law.stackexchange.com) | 396 | 4 | 1 |
| [StackExchange.Genealogy](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com) | 56 | 1 | 1 |
| [StackExchange.Sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) | 57 | 1 | 1 |
| [StackExchange.Space](https://space.stackexchange.com) | 624 | 12 | 1 |
| [StackExchange.Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com) | 101 | 2 | 1 |
| [StackExchange.Tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com) | 2270 | 40 | 1 |
| [StackExchange.Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com) | 101 | 1 | 0 |
| [StackExchange.Or](https://or.stackexchange.com) | 313 | 1 | 0 |
| [StackExchange.Networkengineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com) | 124 | 1 | 0 |
| [StackExchange.Gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com) | 136 | 1 | 0 |
| [StackExchange.Cs](https://cs.stackexchange.com) | 292 | 1 | 0 |
| [StackExchange.Economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com) | 240 | 1 | 0 |
| [StackExchange.Drones](https://drones.stackexchange.com) | 90 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com) | 175 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Elementaryos](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com) | 0 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Earthscience](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com) | 53 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Ebooks](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com) | 0 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Craftcms](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com) | 46 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Freelancing](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com) | 2 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Eosio](https://eosio.stackexchange.com) | 0 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com) | 22 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Expressionengine](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com) | 0 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Ham](https://ham.stackexchange.com) | 100 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Hardwarerecs](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com) | 2 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Cseducators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com) | 14 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com) | 43 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Coffee](https://coffee.stackexchange.com) | 2 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Computergraphics](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com) | 12 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Conlang](https://conlang.stackexchange.com) | 7 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Civicrm](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com) | 83 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com) | 206 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com) | 207 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Audio](https://video.stackexchange.com) | 10 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Beer](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com) | 0 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com) | 140 | 0 |  |
| [StackApps](https://stackapps.com) | 0 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Android](https://android.stackexchange.com) | 75 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com) | 28 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Homebrew](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com) | 8 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Iot](https://iot.stackexchange.com) | 8 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Iota](https://iota.stackexchange.com) | 1 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Italian](https://italian.stackexchange.com) | 22 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Korean](https://korean.stackexchange.com) | 14 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Languagelearning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com) | 0 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com) | 283 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com) | 16 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Joomla](https://joomla.stackexchange.com) | 9 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com) | 206 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com) | 0 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Moderators](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com) | 1 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Monero](https://monero.stackexchange.com) | 8 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Opendata](https://opendata.stackexchange.com) | 3 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Mythology](https://mythology.stackexchange.com) | 2 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com) | 43 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com) | 7 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Poker](https://poker.stackexchange.com) | 4 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Portuguese](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com) | 22 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Sitecore](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com) | 39 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) | 9 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Sound](https://sound.stackexchange.com) | 2 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Scicomp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com) | 69 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Rus](https://rus.stackexchange.com) | 0 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com) | 76 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Reverseengineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com) | 22 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com) | 9 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Tezos](https://tezos.stackexchange.com) | 28 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com) | 0 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Sports](https://sports.stackexchange.com) | 23 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Stellar](https://stellar.stackexchange.com) | 0 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Sustainability](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com) | 9 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com) | 90 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Windowsphone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com) | 0 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Ukrainian](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com) | 2 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Tridion](https://tridion.stackexchange.com) | 28 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Vegetarian](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com) | 0 | 0 |  |
| [StackExchange.Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com) | 46 | 0 |  |
| [StackOverflow.Br](https://pt.stackoverflow.com) | 0 | 0 |  |
| [StackOverflow.Es](https://es.stackoverflow.com) | 0 | 0 |  |
| [StackOverflow.Ja](https://ja.stackoverflow.com) | 0 | 0 |  |
| [StackOverflow.Ru](https://ru.stackoverflow.com) | 0 | 0 |  |

Comment: I wonder how some questions have tons of HNQ's and others very little. It's definetly not the size of the sites that plays a role here, as the trilogy sites would be far more present by that definition.

Comment: Great stats (and a cool query!) Thank you!

Comment: For Spanish, 2/101 becomes 1%... heavy truncating (instead of rounding) going on there...

Comment: Worth mentioning that questions from Stack Overflow, Software Engineering ("StackExchange.Programmers"), and The Workplace are subject to a [penalty factor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316906/377214) when calculating eligibility for HNQ, which means those questions require higher hotness scores than usual to be selected. SO would have had five times as many HNQs and the latter two would have had nearly twice as many HNQs had it not been for said penalty factors. (cc @Luuklag)

Comment: Also, Mathematics has an artificially high number of Hot Network Questions produced because the moderators there have been removing questions from there very often (to the point where the majority of uses of this feature across the network are from that site), and whenever one gets removed, the system selects another to replace it. See [their policy on removing questions from HNQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30672/536049).

Comment: @Luuklag Voting is the primary determinant, so sites with people who are more likely to vote tend to be higher than others. Having multiple answers is the secondary, so sites that have tend towards more answers per question tend to be on the list more. Sites that do both are the top-appearing sites.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog for the sake of accuracy, due to misunderstanding of the implementors about how system works the penalty you mention has noticeable (and I would say overall detrimental) impact only on Stack Overflow. As for all other sites you can consider it absent. Workplace is a great example of implementors misunderstanding: its penalty was introduced to address case of 5 site questions in the hot list but even after getting it there were observed cases of 6-7-8 site questions in the list

Comment: @Luuklag let me tell you a little dirty secret: as of now site presence there is basically a random mess without any sensible purpose / criteria. It made some sense in the past when the purpose of HNQ was to entertain Stack Overflow users but this purpose eventually has proven to be [troublesome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316934) and they attempted to change it to something less slippery. However, these changes were abandoned midway and what we have for last ~two years can be most accurately qualified as under-construction chaos (not that I complain - it's anyway better than before)

Comment: The stats would be more useful if it compared with the site overall close percentage!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen sure, but I don't have that. SEDE doesn't include deleted posts and many closed posts (with negative scores) are deleted.