# Revision history shows all the text changed - post stored as one long line with &#xD;&#xA; instead of line breaks

Tags: bug, meta, specific-question, revisions-list

For example, look at this edit history:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/359735/revisions

It looks like every single revision replaced all the text in the post, even when the revision comment says something like "deleted 1 character in body".

(I was unable to repro [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/358670/revisions) so there is probably something more going on here.)

Examining [revision 11](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/73384dd6-c6e2-4ec1-9ede-3797b141878b/view-source) and [revision 10](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/b5ef735b-3aba-4ec0-a616-8c48210f1093/view-source) in my browser, they look fine; but fetching them with `curl` and doing a `diff` reveals that they are indeed both formatted as one loooooong line with the newlines represented as `&#xD;&#xA;` (CR+LF). Why were the line breaks in that post saved as HTML entities in the rendered HTML, instead of line breaks? In the Markdown, they were typed as normal line breaks.

Comment: That first revision looks [okay to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scA5m.png) in side-by-side markdown, only inline and side-by-side seem broken. I indeed can't repro on the other post...

Comment: I partly repro'd: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/358670/revisions

Comment: @Luuklag That doesn't look like a repro to me; it only highlights the parts which actually changed.

Comment: I tried some other posts containing tables and wasn't able to reproduce.

Comment: I experimentally retyped all the newlines in the post in rev 12; let's see ...

Comment: @Sonic Thanks for the edit; but do we _know_ that Nicolas actually typed in that table? I would wager that he copy/pasted it from somewhere, possibly from Windows hell.

Comment: The earlier diffs in https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/359131/revisions until revision 39 look as if the whole table was replaced, but diffs for subsequent edits look just fine. Something in the diff algorithm must have changed on Jan 5.

Comment: Rev2 says "185 identical lines skipped" (expanded and SbS), which results from not *diffing* and counting correctly; where a huge difference is revealed by the inline view. I [agree tripleee](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359760/revision-history-shows-all-the-text-changed-post-stored-as-one-long-line-with#comment1200690_359760) it's a virtual certainty that the table wasn't typed manually, it was generated and imported then exported - in a format that isn't strictly SE CommonMark, but it's good enough to display well, being processed by the *Editor Diff* is another matter entirely.