# 2021: a year in closing

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopened-questions

I am thrilled to share that this year we are continuing [Shog9’s tradition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359735/2020-a-year-in-closing) of sharing numbers on closed posts across the network. Please welcome stats that highlight how many questions were closed on different Stack Exchange sites in 2021:

| Site | Asked | Asked And Closed | Percent Asked And Closed | All Closed | Duplicates Closed | Duplicates Reopened | Off-Topic Closed | Off-Topic Reopened | Unclear Closed | Unclear Reopened | Too Broad Closed | Too Broad Reopened | Opinion Based Closed | Opinion Based Reopened |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Meta Stack Exchange | 8,602 | 4,873 | 56.65% | 5,204 | 1,264 | 51 | 3,836 | 41 | 76 | 8 | 15 | 3 | 13 | 1 |
| Stack Overflow | 2,637,207 | 438,198 | 16.62% | 454,987 | 142,760 | 4,165 | 127,895 | 1,859 | 106,048 | 2,097 | 61,079 | 842 | 17,205 | 222 |
| Super User | 40,841 | 6,459 | 15.81% | 6,601 | 1,044 | 50 | 3,538 | 47 | 1,523 | 68 | 162 | 7 | 334 | 8 |
| Server Fault | 20,918 | 3,055 | 14.60% | 3,154 | 236 | 2 | 2,375 | 7 | 433 | 1 | 59 | 2 | 51 | 0 |
| Stack Apps | 202 | 27 | 13.37% | 41 | 6 | 0 | 32 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Seasoned Advice | 1,538 | 382 | 24.84% | 399 | 174 | 8 | 102 | 6 | 32 | 4 | 16 | 3 | 75 | 2 |
| Home Improvement | 9,228 | 743 | 8.05% | 931 | 114 | 5 | 352 | 11 | 300 | 6 | 63 | 0 | 102 | 1 |
| Game Developers | 4,390 | 662 | 15.08% | 773 | 117 | 7 | 444 | 21 | 106 | 7 | 59 | 3 | 47 | 0 |
| Arqade | 5,022 | 1,095 | 21.80% | 1,228 | 443 | 6 | 409 | 16 | 277 | 9 | 28 | 5 | 71 | 2 |
| Geographic Information Systems | 17,264 | 3,511 | 20.34% | 3,816 | 523 | 25 | 1,685 | 159 | 899 | 90 | 574 | 89 | 135 | 1 |
| Mathematics | 198,579 | 42,932 | 21.62% | 45,376 | 8,696 | 242 | 31,401 | 662 | 4,300 | 83 | 620 | 35 | 359 | 9 |
| Photography | 1,251 | 230 | 18.39% | 241 | 68 | 3 | 131 | 7 | 27 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 10 | 0 |
| Statistical Analysis | 31,486 | 6,564 | 20.85% | 7,256 | 1,471 | 60 | 2,485 | 95 | 2,891 | 305 | 346 | 35 | 63 | 5 |
| Web Applications | 4,397 | 1,208 | 27.47% | 1,311 | 231 | 4 | 702 | 14 | 299 | 14 | 55 | 2 | 24 | 3 |
| Pro Webmasters | 2,460 | 968 | 39.35% | 991 | 163 | 2 | 469 | 28 | 207 | 37 | 85 | 11 | 67 | 4 |
| Apple | 11,485 | 1,635 | 14.24% | 1,732 | 533 | 24 | 563 | 42 | 468 | 98 | 79 | 14 | 89 | 8 |
| Theoretical Computer Science | 1,180 | 230 | 19.49% | 237 | 3 | 0 | 212 | 0 | 12 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| English Language & Usage | 11,267 | 6,819 | 60.52% | 7,427 | 1,212 | 55 | 4,600 | 205 | 779 | 67 | 123 | 8 | 713 | 41 |
| Personal Finance & Money | 4,279 | 858 | 20.05% | 890 | 181 | 9 | 450 | 12 | 113 | 4 | 47 | 0 | 99 | 4 |
| Role-playing Games | 3,479 | 963 | 27.68% | 1,135 | 393 | 96 | 204 | 19 | 298 | 107 | 83 | 32 | 157 | 31 |
| TeX - LaTeX | 22,221 | 2,740 | 12.33% | 3,116 | 1,458 | 60 | 654 | 9 | 877 | 33 | 55 | 2 | 72 | 6 |
| Ask Ubuntu | 42,236 | 6,443 | 15.25% | 6,689 | 2,377 | 30 | 2,940 | 30 | 1,006 | 20 | 105 | 7 | 261 | 3 |
| Unix & Linux | 25,226 | 2,363 | 9.37% | 2,546 | 947 | 31 | 570 | 3 | 745 | 19 | 112 | 2 | 172 | 3 |
| WordPress | 10,681 | 3,020 | 28.27% | 3,189 | 81 | 4 | 2,712 | 20 | 218 | 4 | 100 | 0 | 78 | 3 |
| Bicycles | 1,782 | 176 | 9.88% | 189 | 59 | 0 | 79 | 1 | 30 | 1 | 6 | 0 | 15 | 1 |
| Software Engineering | 5,490 | 2,246 | 40.91% | 2,262 | 89 | 0 | 1,157 | 12 | 262 | 5 | 448 | 13 | 306 | 12 |
| Android Enthusiasts | 4,854 | 1,050 | 21.63% | 1,210 | 317 | 10 | 643 | 23 | 188 | 22 | 48 | 2 | 14 | 1 |
| Board & Card Games | 717 | 118 | 16.46% | 122 | 46 | 7 | 32 | 1 | 18 | 5 | 10 | 1 | 16 | 0 |
| Physics | 35,193 | 10,049 | 28.55% | 10,453 | 2,006 | 56 | 5,650 | 57 | 1,884 | 69 | 519 | 49 | 394 | 13 |
| Homebrewing | 152 | 2 | 1.32% | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Information Security | 6,488 | 2,682 | 41.34% | 2,738 | 423 | 9 | 1,540 | 18 | 482 | 25 | 97 | 1 | 196 | 3 |
| Writing | 1,241 | 362 | 29.17% | 378 | 58 | 0 | 247 | 4 | 24 | 0 | 16 | 2 | 33 | 1 |
| Electrical Engineering | 24,877 | 4,803 | 19.31% | 4,890 | 365 | 10 | 2,103 | 57 | 1,624 | 57 | 537 | 6 | 261 | 7 |
| Graphic Design | 2,742 | 337 | 12.29% | 348 | 71 | 4 | 150 | 4 | 53 | 0 | 52 | 0 | 22 | 0 |
| Database Administrators | 9,470 | 1,872 | 19.77% | 2,113 | 306 | 6 | 892 | 10 | 641 | 28 | 191 | 7 | 83 | 0 |
| Science Fiction & Fantasy | 5,420 | 1,160 | 21.40% | 1,304 | 528 | 26 | 307 | 33 | 197 | 51 | 65 | 15 | 207 | 39 |
| Area 51 Discussions | 154 | 13 | 8.44% | 13 | 2 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Code Review | 6,610 | 1,634 | 24.72% | 1,657 | 22 | 0 | 1,494 | 46 | 135 | 6 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 0 |
| Code Golf | 1,228 | 410 | 33.39% | 471 | 85 | 10 | 166 | 9 | 211 | 38 | 6 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| Quantitative Finance | 3,613 | 630 | 17.44% | 646 | 50 | 0 | 408 | 0 | 114 | 2 | 41 | 0 | 33 | 0 |
| Project Management | 486 | 89 | 18.31% | 94 | 6 | 0 | 56 | 0 | 12 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 15 | 0 |
| Skeptics | 803 | 284 | 35.37% | 289 | 22 | 1 | 178 | 17 | 42 | 12 | 25 | 8 | 22 | 2 |
| Drupal Answers | 3,946 | 827 | 20.96% | 1,145 | 125 | 2 | 221 | 1 | 650 | 8 | 108 | 1 | 41 | 0 |
| Fitness and Nutrition | 669 | 203 | 30.34% | 214 | 23 | 1 | 141 | 2 | 28 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 20 | 1 |
| Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair | 1,805 | 281 | 15.57% | 288 | 32 | 0 | 122 | 1 | 86 | 1 | 7 | 0 | 41 | 1 |
| Parenting | 358 | 98 | 27.37% | 101 | 6 | 0 | 54 | 3 | 7 | 0 | 9 | 1 | 25 | 0 |
| SharePoint | 4,593 | 183 | 3.98% | 185 | 20 | 1 | 75 | 0 | 74 | 6 | 11 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| Music: Practice and Theory | 2,812 | 823 | 29.27% | 970 | 246 | 12 | 409 | 23 | 144 | 8 | 51 | 3 | 120 | 5 |
| Software Quality Assurance * Testing | 860 | 177 | 20.58% | 195 | 10 | 0 | 44 | 1 | 97 | 5 | 28 | 1 | 16 | 0 |
| Mi Yodeya | 2,628 | 511 | 19.44% | 524 | 162 | 1 | 196 | 18 | 98 | 8 | 23 | 2 | 45 | 1 |
| Astronomy | 2,282 | 382 | 16.74% | 392 | 96 | 5 | 151 | 7 | 90 | 3 | 28 | 1 | 27 | 2 |
| German Language | 1,305 | 279 | 21.38% | 283 | 64 | 3 | 116 | 7 | 74 | 4 | 12 | 0 | 17 | 0 |
| Japanese Language | 2,667 | 638 | 23.92% | 657 | 253 | 5 | 303 | 5 | 67 | 3 | 7 | 1 | 27 | 0 |
| Gardening & Landscaping | 1,559 | 46 | 2.95% | 53 | 3 | 0 | 26 | 0 | 19 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| Philosophy | 2,269 | 465 | 20.49% | 504 | 21 | 1 | 301 | 6 | 89 | 0 | 30 | 0 | 63 | 0 |
| Travel | 2,337 | 704 | 30.12% | 741 | 206 | 10 | 321 | 20 | 117 | 12 | 18 | 1 | 79 | 7 |
| Cryptography | 3,595 | 694 | 19.30% | 717 | 126 | 5 | 475 | 22 | 61 | 2 | 33 | 4 | 22 | 3 |
| Literature | 1,262 | 170 | 13.47% | 190 | 18 | 0 | 88 | 8 | 41 | 3 | 12 | 1 | 31 | 3 |
| Signal Processing | 3,355 | 375 | 11.18% | 384 | 45 | 4 | 198 | 2 | 98 | 10 | 33 | 0 | 10 | 1 |
| French Language | 1,264 | 150 | 11.87% | 152 | 65 | 2 | 51 | 1 | 17 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 9 | 0 |
| Christianity | 1,820 | 497 | 27.31% | 532 | 91 | 10 | 269 | 24 | 65 | 6 | 36 | 7 | 71 | 7 |
| Bitcoin | 4,238 | 1,234 | 29.12% | 1,324 | 376 | 7 | 739 | 10 | 119 | 5 | 24 | 1 | 66 | 3 |
| Linguistics | 1,318 | 345 | 26.18% | 354 | 10 | 0 | 210 | 3 | 83 | 6 | 16 | 1 | 35 | 1 |
| Biblical Hermeneutics | 3,232 | 669 | 20.70% | 738 | 171 | 8 | 367 | 31 | 86 | 11 | 22 | 8 | 92 | 11 |
| Economics | 2,894 | 709 | 24.50% | 734 | 45 | 2 | 398 | 8 | 176 | 0 | 35 | 1 | 80 | 5 |
| History | 1,552 | 604 | 38.92% | 611 | 30 | 1 | 278 | 22 | 134 | 6 | 86 | 3 | 83 | 14 |
| Bricks | 410 | 44 | 10.73% | 47 | 13 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 18 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| Spanish Language | 574 | 66 | 11.50% | 69 | 12 | 0 | 52 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Computational Science | 1,192 | 150 | 12.58% | 157 | 4 | 0 | 115 | 4 | 36 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Movies | 1,550 | 543 | 35.03% | 553 | 39 | 0 | 316 | 10 | 77 | 5 | 33 | 4 | 88 | 5 |
| Chinese Language | 1,130 | 104 | 9.20% | 107 | 10 | 0 | 41 | 2 | 19 | 3 | 6 | 0 | 31 | 0 |
| Biology | 3,078 | 912 | 29.63% | 966 | 108 | 2 | 524 | 10 | 168 | 3 | 54 | 1 | 112 | 0 |
| Poker | 170 | 29 | 17.06% | 31 | 12 | 0 | 10 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Mathematica | 9,085 | 2,006 | 22.08% | 2,058 | 306 | 9 | 1,494 | 14 | 230 | 14 | 18 | 1 | 10 | 0 |
| Psychology & Neuroscience | 1,051 | 365 | 34.73% | 430 | 52 | 3 | 229 | 4 | 43 | 0 | 48 | 1 | 58 | 2 |
| The Great Outdoors | 339 | 66 | 19.47% | 70 | 7 | 1 | 42 | 2 | 12 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 1 |
| Martial Arts | 230 | 21 | 9.13% | 21 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 4 | 1 | 7 | 1 |
| Sports | 480 | 102 | 21.25% | 109 | 25 | 4 | 42 | 3 | 9 | 2 | 7 | 0 | 26 | 1 |
| Academia | 5,339 | 1,889 | 35.38% | 1,979 | 426 | 12 | 1,220 | 18 | 150 | 5 | 55 | 0 | 128 | 4 |
| Computer Science | 6,859 | 942 | 13.73% | 959 | 181 | 2 | 447 | 6 | 229 | 9 | 75 | 4 | 27 | 0 |
| The Workplace | 2,500 | 789 | 31.56% | 793 | 87 | 4 | 462 | 17 | 70 | 0 | 56 | 0 | 118 | 4 |
| Windows Phone | 16 | 6 | 37.50% | 6 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Chemistry | 8,260 | 4,102 | 49.66% | 4,208 | 530 | 10 | 2,055 | 59 | 1,316 | 57 | 211 | 10 | 96 | 3 |
| Chess | 1,114 | 239 | 21.45% | 266 | 73 | 3 | 43 | 3 | 39 | 7 | 31 | 9 | 80 | 10 |
| Raspberry Pi | 4,321 | 696 | 16.11% | 803 | 71 | 0 | 470 | 11 | 198 | 14 | 20 | 0 | 44 | 0 |
| Russian Language | 287 | 98 | 34.15% | 99 | 5 | 0 | 74 | 10 | 19 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Islam | 3,396 | 804 | 23.67% | 850 | 305 | 1 | 239 | 0 | 186 | 1 | 55 | 0 | 65 | 0 |
| Salesforce | 16,464 | 3,695 | 22.44% | 3,748 | 677 | 10 | 2,170 | 25 | 709 | 1 | 59 | 0 | 133 | 2 |
| Ask Patents | 277 | 31 | 11.19% | 32 | 0 | 0 | 30 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| User Experience | 1,483 | 372 | 25.08% | 531 | 40 | 0 | 218 | 1 | 146 | 1 | 28 | 2 | 99 | 1 |
| Genealogy and Family History | 270 | 65 | 24.07% | 72 | 43 | 2 | 12 | 1 | 11 | 4 | 3 | 0 | 3 | 1 |
| Robotics | 782 | 105 | 13.43% | 110 | 3 | 0 | 41 | 0 | 24 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 37 | 0 |
| ExpressionEngine | 82 | 1 | 1.22% | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Politics | 2,426 | 886 | 36.52% | 928 | 137 | 19 | 490 | 63 | 117 | 16 | 65 | 13 | 119 | 13 |
| Video Production | 1,041 | 72 | 6.92% | 78 | 6 | 0 | 47 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 13 | 0 |
| Anime & Manga | 1,116 | 412 | 36.92% | 425 | 49 | 0 | 279 | 2 | 35 | 3 | 9 | 1 | 53 | 0 |
| Magento | 8,702 | 124 | 1.42% | 145 | 27 | 0 | 41 | 0 | 61 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 14 | 0 |
| English Language Learners | 13,918 | 2,604 | 18.71% | 2,803 | 575 | 8 | 1,562 | 39 | 420 | 20 | 83 | 8 | 163 | 11 |
| Sustainable Living | 203 | 21 | 10.34% | 25 | 5 | 0 | 6 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| Tridion | 171 | 2 | 1.17% | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Reverse Engineering | 1,209 | 68 | 5.62% | 76 | 5 | 0 | 35 | 0 | 27 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 7 | 0 |
| Arduino | 3,137 | 970 | 30.92% | 1,277 | 98 | 3 | 449 | 7 | 474 | 13 | 240 | 12 | 16 | 2 |
| Network Engineering | 3,000 | 2,026 | 67.53% | 2,046 | 139 | 5 | 1,507 | 8 | 326 | 37 | 15 | 1 | 59 | 4 |
| Open Data | 447 | 17 | 3.80% | 17 | 1 | 0 | 14 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Freelancing | 149 | 31 | 20.81% | 32 | 2 | 0 | 16 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 8 | 0 |
| Blender | 20,823 | 4,398 | 21.12% | 4,570 | 1,929 | 83 | 753 | 17 | 1,521 | 153 | 201 | 15 | 166 | 4 |
| MathOverflow | 17,168 | 3,202 | 18.65% | 3,244 | 67 | 2 | 2,901 | 28 | 236 | 4 | 27 | 2 | 13 | 1 |
| Space Exploration | 2,503 | 311 | 12.43% | 321 | 78 | 4 | 116 | 14 | 63 | 7 | 32 | 1 | 32 | 4 |
| Sound Design | 536 | 183 | 34.14% | 205 | 14 | 0 | 164 | 4 | 15 | 0 | 4 | 1 | 8 | 0 |
| Tor | 479 | 15 | 3.13% | 26 | 10 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Pets | 752 | 173 | 23.01% | 210 | 103 | 1 | 54 | 0 | 28 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 18 | 1 |
| Amateur Radio | 512 | 72 | 14.06% | 72 | 6 | 1 | 36 | 3 | 23 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 5 | 2 |
| Italian Language | 170 | 19 | 11.18% | 19 | 1 | 0 | 17 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Stack Overflow em Português | 31,315 | 17,750 | 56.68% | 18,566 | 742 | 20 | 14,771 | 193 | 2,340 | 50 | 587 | 2 | 126 | 1 |
| Aviation | 2,442 | 633 | 25.92% | 654 | 191 | 8 | 191 | 10 | 150 | 13 | 50 | 4 | 72 | 5 |
| Ebooks | 107 | 9 | 8.41% | 9 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Beer, Wine & Spirits | 70 | 7 | 10.00% | 7 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Software Recommendations | 2,474 | 212 | 8.57% | 216 | 8 | 0 | 174 | 10 | 34 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| CS50 | 1,008 | 27 | 2.68% | 30 | 5 | 0 | 18 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Expatriates | 695 | 89 | 12.81% | 100 | 27 | 1 | 31 | 0 | 13 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 19 | 1 |
| Mathematics Educators | 369 | 72 | 19.51% | 73 | 2 | 0 | 46 | 0 | 12 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 9 | 0 |
| Earth Science | 754 | 124 | 16.45% | 130 | 21 | 0 | 63 | 3 | 28 | 1 | 10 | 0 | 8 | 0 |
| Joomla | 473 | 15 | 3.17% | 16 | 4 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Data Science | 8,449 | 1,284 | 15.20% | 1,383 | 50 | 1 | 549 | 1 | 470 | 6 | 193 | 5 | 121 | 0 |
| Puzzling | 2,328 | 430 | 18.47% | 545 | 71 | 0 | 396 | 31 | 46 | 5 | 13 | 1 | 19 | 0 |
| Craft CMS | 1,001 | 4 | 0.40% | 6 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Buddhism | 631 | 82 | 13.00% | 87 | 40 | 4 | 22 | 7 | 15 | 4 | 1 | 0 | 9 | 5 |
| Hinduism | 2,603 | 434 | 16.67% | 466 | 236 | 5 | 121 | 6 | 28 | 1 | 13 | 1 | 68 | 4 |
| Community Building | 26 | 4 | 15.38% | 5 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Worldbuilding | 4,861 | 1,376 | 28.31% | 1,401 | 151 | 17 | 432 | 34 | 316 | 37 | 242 | 34 | 260 | 18 |
| スタック・オーバーフロー | 4,230 | 282 | 6.67% | 285 | 25 | 1 | 143 | 12 | 89 | 5 | 14 | 1 | 14 | 0 |
| Emacs | 2,806 | 51 | 1.82% | 53 | 38 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 4 | 1 |
| History of Science & Mathematics | 640 | 81 | 12.66% | 83 | 21 | 0 | 36 | 0 | 9 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 14 | 0 |
| Lifehacks | 248 | 80 | 32.26% | 82 | 7 | 0 | 72 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Engineering | 3,015 | 571 | 18.94% | 579 | 24 | 0 | 140 | 1 | 302 | 10 | 56 | 0 | 57 | 0 |
| Coffee | 102 | 12 | 11.76% | 14 | 5 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| Vi and Vim | 1,828 | 152 | 8.32% | 163 | 69 | 3 | 56 | 0 | 27 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 8 | 0 |
| Music Fans | 452 | 50 | 11.06% | 59 | 6 | 0 | 44 | 4 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Woodworking | 393 | 50 | 12.72% | 53 | 11 | 0 | 22 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| CiviCRM | 1,225 | 5 | 0.41% | 5 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Health | 1,506 | 709 | 47.08% | 757 | 23 | 1 | 615 | 20 | 44 | 2 | 15 | 2 | 60 | 1 |
| Stack Overflow на русском | 80,891 | 12,826 | 15.86% | 13,086 | 2,018 | 54 | 5,634 | 121 | 2,881 | 62 | 1,428 | 13 | 1,125 | 10 |
| Русский язык | 1,322 | 79 | 5.98% | 82 | 14 | 1 | 28 | 2 | 21 | 1 | 10 | 2 | 9 | 0 |
| Mythology | 167 | 22 | 13.17% | 25 | 1 | 0 | 10 | 1 | 10 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| Law | 4,475 | 776 | 17.34% | 796 | 132 | 18 | 442 | 41 | 135 | 15 | 37 | 3 | 50 | 7 |
| Open Source | 668 | 110 | 16.47% | 112 | 42 | 1 | 48 | 2 | 11 | 0 | 7 | 1 | 4 | 0 |
| elementary OS | 1,193 | 24 | 2.01% | 25 | 5 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Portuguese Language | 258 | 14 | 5.43% | 14 | 6 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Computer Graphics | 500 | 46 | 9.20% | 49 | 2 | 0 | 35 | 2 | 6 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| Hardware Recommendations | 745 | 209 | 28.05% | 253 | 0 | 0 | 247 | 2 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Stack Overflow en español | 48,537 | 7,656 | 15.77% | 7,885 | 527 | 9 | 1,989 | 68 | 4,327 | 65 | 235 | 5 | 807 | 10 |
| 3D Printing | 1,026 | 91 | 8.87% | 95 | 15 | 1 | 37 | 6 | 27 | 5 | 7 | 0 | 9 | 1 |
| Ethereum | 11,362 | 1,122 | 9.88% | 1,172 | 375 | 4 | 387 | 3 | 275 | 0 | 80 | 0 | 55 | 0 |
| Latin Language | 880 | 60 | 6.82% | 60 | 16 | 3 | 18 | 3 | 24 | 9 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Language Learning | 223 | 112 | 50.22% | 114 | 5 | 0 | 94 | 5 | 7 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 6 | 0 |
| Retrocomputing | 904 | 156 | 17.26% | 164 | 14 | 0 | 93 | 8 | 19 | 2 | 18 | 3 | 20 | 1 |
| Arts and Crafts | 361 | 92 | 25.48% | 95 | 9 | 1 | 49 | 5 | 19 | 5 | 7 | 3 | 11 | 0 |
| Korean Language | 206 | 9 | 4.37% | 11 | 4 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Monero | 444 | 52 | 11.71% | 57 | 50 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 1 |
| Artificial Intelligence | 3,276 | 569 | 17.37% | 1,109 | 56 | 3 | 509 | 4 | 314 | 5 | 171 | 5 | 59 | 0 |
| Esperanto Language | 62 | 3 | 4.84% | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Sitecore | 1,633 | 308 | 18.86% | 328 | 83 | 3 | 90 | 2 | 118 | 27 | 22 | 5 | 15 | 0 |
| Internet of Things | 326 | 63 | 19.33% | 67 | 1 | 0 | 30 | 0 | 19 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 10 | 0 |
| Vegetarianism | 48 | 7 | 14.58% | 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Ukrainian Language | 138 | 11 | 7.97% | 11 | 1 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| DevOps | 1,228 | 94 | 7.65% | 94 | 0 | 0 | 38 | 0 | 24 | 3 | 25 | 0 | 7 | 0 |
| Bioinformatics | 1,071 | 106 | 9.90% | 149 | 14 | 2 | 29 | 10 | 75 | 6 | 10 | 2 | 21 | 2 |
| Computer Science Educators | 168 | 48 | 28.57% | 48 | 0 | 0 | 41 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Interpersonal Skills | 457 | 300 | 65.65% | 302 | 5 | 0 | 180 | 5 | 76 | 7 | 6 | 0 | 35 | 0 |
| Iota | 120 | 4 | 3.33% | 4 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Stellar | 362 | 71 | 19.61% | 74 | 33 | 0 | 16 | 0 | 19 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| Constructed Languages | 58 | 5 | 8.62% | 5 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Quantum Computing | 2,424 | 258 | 10.64% | 272 | 69 | 2 | 58 | 1 | 98 | 9 | 38 | 6 | 9 | 1 |
| EOS.IO | 218 | 15 | 6.88% | 16 | 4 | 0 | 9 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Tezos | 422 | 7 | 1.66% | 8 | 1 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Operations Research | 970 | 43 | 4.43% | 45 | 10 | 0 | 16 | 1 | 16 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Drones and Model Aircraft | 204 | 11 | 5.39% | 11 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Matter Modeling | 984 | 111 | 11.28% | 147 | 11 | 0 | 12 | 4 | 116 | 11 | 7 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Cardano | 1,234 | 64 | 5.19% | 64 | 9 | 0 | 33 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 12 | 0 |

#### Notes

- This counts questions asked in 2021 and questions closed in 2021 - the AskedAndClosed and PctAskedAndClosed columns reflect questions that were *both* asked and closed in 2021, while the remaining columns total up all questions closed in 2021 - even those asked in prior years.
- Reopen numbers also include questions asked in years prior - but limit themselves to questions that were closed in 2021 and then also reopened in 2021.
- If a question was closed twice, it'll be counted twice.
- If a question was reopened twice, it'll be counted twice.

### Alternate formats

- CSV: https://gist.github.com/chabanovsky/1ad9dd05839bc35f203201ff69e87e47

Comment: Interestingly, how stable the closed question fraction is. 15-20% and not changing much year over year. However, I don't really believe that on SO from 2.6m new questions only 140k were duplicates. One could pick 100 randomly, check carefully and see if the incidence in the test set is compatible with 1 in 18 as suggested by the closure rate.

Comment: @Trilarion a lot of the duplicates will have multiple issues and [end up closed for one of the other reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/413630).

Comment: @bad_coder Could be, but even that would mean that in 2021 people managed to ask up to 2.2m new questions on SO on top of the 20+m existing questions. I would even bet against that. My bet would be that there are lots of non-closed questions that are duplicates, at least on SO (can't really say for the other sites).

Comment: @Trilarion On SO notice the 14.3% reduction in questions asked for a marginal 0.41% increase in closing rate. Closing around half a million questions per year is no small feat so the system is being effective.

Comment: Cool stats but it'd be nice to [add the ability to lexicographically sort data in a column](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357021/178179).

Comment: Surprising how many sites have a close rate over 50%. How do they still have traffic?

Comment: +999 for use of Markdown tables compared to previous years. This is a HUGE improvement!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Thanks! Now I need to wonder if I need to get depressed over of the off topic close rate (jk)

Answer (score 4):

This year's stats are surprising in that the *"Too broad"* close reason has the second lowest reopen rate, **1.379%** (only *"opinion based"* has a lower rate of 1.29%).

There was some discussion if *"Too broad"* needed more subcategories (for reference, see [Do we really need more focus?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402523) and [Is the description to "needs more focus" confusing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403330)).
But it turns out the *"Too broad"* reason is being twice more efficient than the *"Duplicate"* close reason, which we'd expect intuitively to be the most pinpointed closures.

<sub>Numbers are for Stack Overflow.</sub>

| Close reason | Closed | Reopened | Percentage reopened |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Duplicates | 142760 | 4165 | 2.917% |
| Off-topic | 127895 | 1859 | 1.454% |
| Unclear | 106048 | 2097 | 1.977% |
| Too broad | 61079 | 842 | **1.379%** |
| Opinion based | 17205 | 222 | 1.29% |

Comment: The stats in your post  *only* refer to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Mari-LouA the post says so above the table. SO is the only site where *"Too broad"* reopened posts reached 3 digits, on the few other sites where it reached 2 digits any conclusion is likely to be localized so it should be written by a member of that specific community.