# Get statistics about self-deleted accounts

Tags: support, moderator-tools, data-explorer, statistics, deleted-accounts

It's interesting to know is there a possibility to get the number of deleted users on site per specified period?

Additional information like reputation, number of posts etc on the moment of deletion would also be helpful.

Any approach is appropriate: high rep user tools, SEDE, diamond moderator tools.

<sub>Notice for possible downvoters: this is not just my desire to get info only to get it, such type of data is very useful as an index of community health. And I as a moderator very interested on this.</sub>

Comment: We already get this for each site annually i.e. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375072/2021-a-year-in-moderation

Comment: @RobertLongson the statistics you're referring is about users deleted/destroyed by moderators only. I'm interested for self-deletion mostly.

Comment: self deletion is the Community column.

Comment: @RobertLongson so zero self deletions in whole of 2022? That doesn't make sense, also only 10 deleted by mods is way too low. That stat is either bugged or wrong on purpose.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry most users were destroyed by mods rather than deleted.

Comment: Still, the 0 in both 2021 and 2022 means it's a bug. No way that nobody deleted their account for two years.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ maybe worth posting a bug report about it, that the "year in moderation" stats are bugged. (You might get a response "we don't keep track of self deletions" but still, better chance if posted that way.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard feel free to post it by self, since I'm not sure that "deleted by Community" means "self-deletion".

Comment: [Total missing users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1808994) (both deleted and where the id sequence on the primary key skipped 1024 numbers)