# 2022: a year in closing

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopened-questions

Let’s take a look at how last year looks in terms of closing across the network. Please welcome stats that highlight how many questions were closed on different Stack Exchange sites in 2022.

[The same data in CSV format](https://gist.github.com/chabanovsky/3bc0148a6bc18eac57d889220ece4a40). [Data for 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374784/2021-a-year-in-closing).

| Site | Asked | Asked And Closed | Percent Asked And Closed | All Closed | Duplicates Closed | Duplicates Reopened | Off-Topic Closed | Off-Topic Reopened | Unclear Closed | Unclear Reopened | Too Broad Closed | Too Broad Reopened | Opinion Based Closed | Opinion Based Reopened |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Network Engineering | 2,259 | 1,570 | 69.5% | 1,584 | 102 | 3 | 1,219 | 13 | 229 | 47 | 15 | 0 | 19 | 0 |
| Interpersonal Skills | 314 | 210 | 66.88% | 212 | 2 | 0 | 149 | 4 | 42 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 16 | 0 |
| English Language and Usage | 8,102 | 5,144 | 63.49% | 5,475 | 918 | 75 | 3,428 | 224 | 517 | 64 | 77 | 9 | 535 | 53 |
| Medical Sciences | 942 | 540 | 57.32% | 583 | 17 | 0 | 518 | 17 | 22 | 1 | 10 | 0 | 16 | 1 |
| Meta Stack Exchange | 7,149 | 3,990 | 55.81% | 4,586 | 1,073 | 45 | 3,398 | 34 | 95 | 14 | 11 | 1 | 9 | 3 |
| Stack Overflow em Português | 25,226 | 13,519 | 53.59% | 14,135 | 368 | 19 | 12,460 | 151 | 1,084 | 20 | 124 | 0 | 99 | 3 |
| Chemistry | 5,182 | 2,640 | 50.95% | 2,682 | 269 | 9 | 1,060 | 53 | 1,155 | 62 | 148 | 7 | 50 | 4 |
| Software Engineering | 3,835 | 1,866 | 48.66% | 1,900 | 54 | 1 | 914 | 9 | 280 | 11 | 426 | 16 | 226 | 15 |
| Language Learning | 174 | 84 | 48.28% | 85 | 1 | 0 | 78 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| Music Fans | 254 | 108 | 42.52% | 1,157 | 0 | 0 | 1,149 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 7 | 0 |
| Psychology and Neuroscience | 757 | 304 | 40.16% | 346 | 41 | 2 | 152 | 1 | 38 | 1 | 50 | 1 | 65 | 1 |
| History | 1,290 | 499 | 38.68% | 506 | 23 | 1 | 205 | 6 | 132 | 14 | 64 | 6 | 82 | 2 |
| Information Security | 4,678 | 1,774 | 37.92% | 1,818 | 260 | 4 | 1,126 | 15 | 278 | 8 | 33 | 2 | 121 | 3 |
| Webmasters | 1,803 | 673 | 37.33% | 700 | 167 | 6 | 347 | 6 | 97 | 17 | 47 | 7 | 42 | 0 |
| Sound Design | 334 | 123 | 36.83% | 144 | 8 | 1 | 116 | 0 | 10 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| Politics | 2,326 | 817 | 35.12% | 834 | 95 | 12 | 487 | 84 | 82 | 17 | 26 | 6 | 144 | 26 |
| Anime and Manga | 706 | 247 | 34.99% | 952 | 22 | 0 | 869 | 15 | 14 | 1 | 12 | 1 | 35 | 2 |
| Academia | 3,923 | 1,340 | 34.16% | 1,388 | 346 | 4 | 799 | 16 | 113 | 10 | 58 | 4 | 72 | 5 |
| Movies and TV | 1,219 | 407 | 33.39% | 410 | 34 | 0 | 221 | 6 | 68 | 7 | 17 | 3 | 70 | 1 |
| Worldbuilding | 3,878 | 1,281 | 33.03% | 1,308 | 112 | 6 | 448 | 30 | 307 | 23 | 217 | 14 | 224 | 13 |
| Physical Fitness | 464 | 148 | 31.9% | 170 | 22 | 1 | 109 | 1 | 23 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 12 | 2 |
| Skeptics | 593 | 188 | 31.7% | 190 | 8 | 0 | 124 | 5 | 27 | 5 | 19 | 3 | 12 | 2 |
| Quantitative Finance | 2,471 | 769 | 31.12% | 788 | 67 | 1 | 504 | 6 | 136 | 6 | 41 | 1 | 40 | 0 |
| Physics | 27,974 | 8,618 | 30.81% | 8,876 | 1,603 | 70 | 4,597 | 106 | 1,964 | 147 | 412 | 53 | 300 | 16 |
| Lifehacks | 178 | 54 | 30.34% | 54 | 4 | 0 | 38 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Arduino | 2,044 | 603 | 29.5% | 671 | 60 | 3 | 279 | 10 | 236 | 17 | 78 | 6 | 18 | 1 |
| Biology | 2,066 | 595 | 28.8% | 605 | 76 | 1 | 320 | 7 | 102 | 7 | 44 | 1 | 63 | 0 |
| The Workplace | 1,742 | 494 | 28.36% | 495 | 33 | 10 | 348 | 14 | 32 | 5 | 12 | 0 | 70 | 2 |
| Music: Practice and Theory | 1,890 | 534 | 28.25% | 609 | 143 | 9 | 267 | 6 | 92 | 5 | 39 | 3 | 68 | 1 |
| Code Review | 5,055 | 1,386 | 27.42% | 1,426 | 21 | 1 | 1,293 | 40 | 109 | 5 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Project Management | 332 | 88 | 26.51% | 94 | 0 | 0 | 51 | 0 | 20 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 20 | 0 |
| Islam | 1,650 | 435 | 26.36% | 491 | 229 | 0 | 117 | 0 | 86 | 2 | 24 | 1 | 35 | 0 |
| Drupal Answers | 2,988 | 770 | 25.77% | 979 | 109 | 3 | 221 | 5 | 546 | 8 | 64 | 3 | 39 | 0 |
| Russian Language | 199 | 51 | 25.63% | 51 | 3 | 0 | 37 | 3 | 9 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Computer Science Educators | 111 | 28 | 25.23% | 28 | 0 | 0 | 24 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Code Golf | 996 | 250 | 25.1% | 306 | 64 | 9 | 117 | 7 | 119 | 25 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| Parenting | 262 | 65 | 24.81% | 69 | 8 | 0 | 40 | 2 | 7 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 11 | 2 |
| Linguistics | 1,070 | 257 | 24.02% | 262 | 19 | 0 | 153 | 5 | 47 | 1 | 19 | 1 | 24 | 0 |
| WordPress Development | 7,334 | 1,718 | 23.43% | 1,782 | 36 | 1 | 1,504 | 9 | 143 | 2 | 48 | 1 | 51 | 0 |
| Christianity | 1,790 | 418 | 23.35% | 435 | 102 | 10 | 183 | 14 | 59 | 1 | 34 | 3 | 57 | 6 |
| Geographic Information Systems | 16,462 | 3,836 | 23.3% | 4,319 | 435 | 36 | 1,907 | 144 | 1,025 | 94 | 771 | 127 | 181 | 7 |
| Hardware Recommendations | 584 | 136 | 23.29% | 139 | 4 | 0 | 113 | 3 | 14 | 3 | 5 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| Role-playing Games | 2,575 | 597 | 23.18% | 651 | 258 | 70 | 87 | 13 | 156 | 59 | 49 | 16 | 101 | 22 |
| Aviation | 2,020 | 468 | 23.17% | 480 | 100 | 4 | 168 | 5 | 128 | 13 | 35 | 1 | 49 | 4 |
| Artificial Intelligence | 2,971 | 686 | 23.09% | 805 | 31 | 1 | 319 | 2 | 285 | 5 | 123 | 3 | 47 | 0 |
| Pets | 465 | 105 | 22.58% | 105 | 35 | 0 | 30 | 0 | 29 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 8 | 0 |
| Electrical Engineering | 20,323 | 4,532 | 22.3% | 4,583 | 318 | 14 | 1,747 | 72 | 1,661 | 109 | 589 | 21 | 268 | 13 |
| Travel | 2,838 | 624 | 21.99% | 634 | 207 | 5 | 254 | 18 | 99 | 10 | 21 | 1 | 53 | 3 |
| Arqade | 3,148 | 688 | 21.86% | 1,038 | 428 | 9 | 310 | 3 | 221 | 6 | 17 | 1 | 62 | 4 |
| Personal Finance and Money | 2,655 | 577 | 21.73% | 591 | 96 | 4 | 274 | 2 | 79 | 1 | 34 | 0 | 108 | 0 |
| Biblical Hermeneutics | 1,796 | 389 | 21.66% | 419 | 92 | 6 | 215 | 15 | 55 | 6 | 15 | 3 | 42 | 5 |
| Sports | 457 | 98 | 21.44% | 102 | 30 | 0 | 32 | 5 | 14 | 1 | 9 | 1 | 17 | 1 |
| Salesforce | 15,023 | 3,214 | 21.39% | 3,263 | 582 | 9 | 1,984 | 10 | 575 | 2 | 32 | 0 | 90 | 1 |
| Mi Yodeya | 2,232 | 477 | 21.37% | 491 | 197 | 4 | 175 | 10 | 55 | 9 | 27 | 1 | 37 | 4 |
| Freelancing | 80 | 17 | 21.25% | 18 | 2 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Seasoned Advice | 1,122 | 232 | 20.68% | 243 | 97 | 3 | 70 | 4 | 29 | 5 | 2 | 0 | 45 | 3 |
| Philosophy | 2,354 | 485 | 20.6% | 504 | 34 | 2 | 252 | 4 | 131 | 1 | 35 | 2 | 52 | 3 |
| Cross Validated | 26,845 | 5,531 | 20.6% | 6,628 | 1,290 | 57 | 2,319 | 78 | 2,650 | 164 | 294 | 25 | 75 | 6 |
| Software Quality Assurance and Testing | 578 | 119 | 20.59% | 123 | 5 | 0 | 28 | 0 | 61 | 2 | 10 | 0 | 19 | 0 |
| Stack Apps | 225 | 46 | 20.44% | 52 | 13 | 0 | 32 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Mathematics | 148,729 | 29,933 | 20.13% | 31,658 | 7,078 | 238 | 20,121 | 427 | 3,720 | 50 | 510 | 17 | 229 | 4 |
| Mathematica | 7,888 | 1,580 | 20.03% | 1,628 | 253 | 4 | 1,147 | 18 | 206 | 3 | 12 | 0 | 10 | 0 |
| Windows Phone | 10 | 2 | 20.0% | 3 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Arts and Crafts | 245 | 49 | 20.0% | 53 | 1 | 0 | 29 | 4 | 19 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| Mathematics Educators | 317 | 63 | 19.87% | 65 | 4 | 0 | 41 | 2 | 10 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| Web Applications | 3,454 | 682 | 19.75% | 707 | 86 | 0 | 426 | 3 | 161 | 2 | 24 | 1 | 10 | 0 |
| English Language Learners | 10,262 | 1,999 | 19.48% | 2,102 | 261 | 3 | 1,365 | 40 | 308 | 15 | 56 | 5 | 112 | 1 |
| Retrocomputing | 706 | 136 | 19.26% | 142 | 13 | 1 | 75 | 9 | 21 | 1 | 17 | 3 | 16 | 3 |
| Internet of Things | 240 | 46 | 19.17% | 47 | 1 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 20 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Open Source | 496 | 94 | 18.95% | 97 | 46 | 2 | 37 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| Robotics | 684 | 129 | 18.86% | 151 | 2 | 0 | 45 | 1 | 26 | 1 | 19 | 1 | 59 | 0 |
| Cryptography | 3,088 | 582 | 18.85% | 595 | 90 | 3 | 394 | 18 | 76 | 9 | 22 | 2 | 13 | 0 |
| Science Fiction and Fantasy | 4,872 | 909 | 18.66% | 1,012 | 447 | 20 | 236 | 23 | 128 | 35 | 65 | 24 | 136 | 18 |
| Monero | 219 | 40 | 18.26% | 40 | 38 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Genealogy and Family History | 165 | 30 | 18.18% | 31 | 14 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 7 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Bricks | 350 | 63 | 18.0% | 65 | 20 | 1 | 6 | 0 | 32 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Woodworking | 360 | 64 | 17.78% | 71 | 8 | 1 | 37 | 2 | 12 | 0 | 6 | 1 | 8 | 1 |
| The Great Outdoors | 227 | 40 | 17.62% | 44 | 7 | 0 | 25 | 2 | 9 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Sitecore | 1,452 | 255 | 17.56% | 262 | 79 | 1 | 57 | 1 | 105 | 11 | 7 | 0 | 14 | 0 |
| Android Enthusiasts | 3,417 | 595 | 17.41% | 988 | 262 | 10 | 358 | 21 | 343 | 18 | 20 | 1 | 5 | 0 |
| Astronomy | 1,564 | 267 | 17.07% | 274 | 73 | 3 | 74 | 2 | 90 | 7 | 13 | 0 | 24 | 3 |
| Bitcoin | 2,363 | 402 | 17.01% | 453 | 132 | 4 | 241 | 9 | 60 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 12 | 0 |
| Writing | 1,101 | 187 | 16.98% | 194 | 17 | 0 | 134 | 1 | 20 | 3 | 11 | 1 | 12 | 0 |
| MathOverflow | 15,211 | 2,555 | 16.8% | 2,582 | 44 | 1 | 2,305 | 14 | 183 | 2 | 24 | 1 | 26 | 5 |
| Space Exploration | 1,460 | 244 | 16.71% | 257 | 60 | 1 | 87 | 1 | 52 | 1 | 21 | 2 | 37 | 2 |
| Stack Overflow на русском | 71,823 | 11,925 | 16.6% | 12,184 | 1,828 | 47 | 5,846 | 127 | 2,172 | 34 | 1,400 | 11 | 938 | 2 |
| Board and Card Games | 598 | 99 | 16.56% | 103 | 51 | 2 | 19 | 0 | 20 | 8 | 5 | 0 | 8 | 0 |
| User Experience | 1,298 | 215 | 16.56% | 235 | 26 | 0 | 131 | 1 | 43 | 1 | 6 | 0 | 29 | 0 |
| Mythology and Folklore | 121 | 20 | 16.53% | 21 | 3 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Stack Overflow | 2,360,129 | 387,977 | 16.44% | 408,890 | 133,521 | 3,685 | 120,892 | 1,484 | 89,456 | 1,172 | 51,340 | 551 | 13,681 | 125 |
| Japanese Language | 2,429 | 394 | 16.22% | 407 | 142 | 7 | 204 | 3 | 39 | 1 | 7 | 0 | 15 | 1 |
| Puzzling | 1,825 | 296 | 16.22% | 312 | 48 | 1 | 223 | 10 | 26 | 2 | 10 | 1 | 5 | 0 |
| Blender | 18,849 | 3,002 | 15.93% | 3,107 | 1,156 | 53 | 497 | 8 | 1,230 | 136 | 124 | 9 | 100 | 3 |
| Ask Ubuntu | 34,054 | 5,413 | 15.9% | 6,515 | 2,882 | 68 | 2,317 | 54 | 1,043 | 27 | 88 | 7 | 185 | 9 |
| German Language | 1,112 | 176 | 15.83% | 181 | 50 | 4 | 85 | 7 | 31 | 6 | 7 | 1 | 8 | 0 |
| Home Improvement | 8,307 | 1,310 | 15.77% | 1,530 | 128 | 4 | 509 | 12 | 549 | 20 | 154 | 15 | 190 | 6 |
| Chess | 793 | 125 | 15.76% | 142 | 31 | 2 | 17 | 0 | 31 | 7 | 25 | 6 | 38 | 7 |
| Super User | 32,556 | 5,074 | 15.59% | 5,223 | 720 | 31 | 2,757 | 52 | 1,327 | 44 | 135 | 5 | 284 | 5 |
| Poker | 119 | 18 | 15.13% | 19 | 15 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Photography | 913 | 137 | 15.01% | 142 | 43 | 0 | 70 | 2 | 13 | 2 | 5 | 2 | 11 | 0 |
| Veganism and Vegetarianism | 61 | 9 | 14.75% | 11 | 2 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Raspberry Pi | 2,767 | 400 | 14.46% | 432 | 43 | 0 | 279 | 7 | 79 | 9 | 15 | 0 | 16 | 1 |
| Stack Overflow en español | 41,491 | 5,861 | 14.13% | 6,009 | 361 | 5 | 1,798 | 53 | 3,096 | 48 | 210 | 4 | 544 | 3 |
| Matter Modeling | 945 | 130 | 13.76% | 198 | 16 | 0 | 17 | 1 | 159 | 5 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Ask Different | 8,967 | 1,210 | 13.49% | 1,356 | 442 | 20 | 422 | 26 | 367 | 64 | 52 | 15 | 73 | 4 |
| Game Development | 3,141 | 404 | 12.86% | 503 | 85 | 3 | 250 | 12 | 94 | 3 | 40 | 2 | 34 | 0 |
| Earth Science | 646 | 83 | 12.85% | 86 | 8 | 0 | 51 | 1 | 18 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Computational Science | 941 | 119 | 12.65% | 128 | 7 | 0 | 67 | 0 | 46 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| Law | 4,421 | 547 | 12.37% | 556 | 105 | 9 | 294 | 22 | 101 | 8 | 24 | 3 | 32 | 4 |
| Area 51 Discussions | 97 | 12 | 12.37% | 13 | 6 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Engineering | 2,297 | 283 | 12.32% | 304 | 11 | 0 | 99 | 0 | 125 | 2 | 31 | 0 | 38 | 0 |
| TeX - LaTeX | 19,512 | 2,382 | 12.21% | 2,967 | 1,350 | 42 | 575 | 5 | 981 | 35 | 29 | 1 | 32 | 2 |
| Community Building | 25 | 3 | 12.0% | 4 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Amateur Radio | 477 | 57 | 11.95% | 58 | 7 | 1 | 30 | 0 | 15 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| Theoretical Computer Science | 940 | 112 | 11.91% | 116 | 1 | 0 | 108 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Spanish Language | 410 | 48 | 11.71% | 50 | 9 | 0 | 36 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Portuguese Language | 143 | 16 | 11.19% | 19 | 12 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Stellar | 134 | 15 | 11.19% | 16 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Computer Science | 4,665 | 520 | 11.15% | 546 | 100 | 0 | 260 | 1 | 101 | 7 | 78 | 7 | 7 | 0 |
| Buddhism | 469 | 47 | 10.02% | 50 | 20 | 3 | 17 | 4 | 9 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| French Language | 964 | 96 | 9.96% | 98 | 37 | 2 | 41 | 1 | 8 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 9 | 0 |
| Server Fault | 17,393 | 1,729 | 9.94% | 1,792 | 172 | 0 | 1,286 | 4 | 245 | 2 | 43 | 0 | 46 | 0 |
| Graphic Design | 1,953 | 191 | 9.78% | 196 | 38 | 5 | 84 | 1 | 23 | 2 | 34 | 0 | 17 | 0 |
| Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair | 1,440 | 140 | 9.72% | 144 | 12 | 1 | 77 | 1 | 38 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 15 | 0 |
| Literature | 843 | 81 | 9.61% | 82 | 4 | 0 | 42 | 1 | 19 | 2 | 6 | 0 | 11 | 1 |
| Substrate and Polkadot | 3,072 | 292 | 9.51% | 292 | 84 | 0 | 33 | 1 | 119 | 8 | 39 | 1 | 17 | 1 |
| Chinese Language and Usage | 943 | 88 | 9.33% | 95 | 20 | 0 | 48 | 6 | 14 | 4 | 2 | 0 | 11 | 1 |
| History of Science and Mathematics | 506 | 47 | 9.29% | 47 | 10 | 0 | 17 | 0 | 9 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Signal Processing | 2,607 | 239 | 9.17% | 244 | 47 | 2 | 94 | 4 | 81 | 17 | 18 | 3 | 4 | 0 |
| Drones and Model Aircraft | 143 | 13 | 9.09% | 14 | 2 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Bicycles | 1,457 | 132 | 9.06% | 134 | 31 | 0 | 67 | 2 | 29 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 0 |
| Economics | 2,354 | 210 | 8.92% | 214 | 17 | 0 | 138 | 0 | 37 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 14 | 0 |
| Database Administrators | 7,811 | 688 | 8.81% | 750 | 135 | 4 | 328 | 4 | 235 | 7 | 31 | 0 | 21 | 1 |
| DevOps | 1,204 | 106 | 8.8% | 112 | 3 | 0 | 48 | 1 | 38 | 4 | 15 | 1 | 8 | 0 |
| Constructed Languages | 93 | 8 | 8.6% | 8 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Solana | 2,454 | 210 | 8.56% | 210 | 28 | 1 | 40 | 0 | 82 | 1 | 34 | 0 | 26 | 1 |
| Unix and Linux | 21,134 | 1,797 | 8.5% | 2,008 | 769 | 37 | 486 | 16 | 602 | 11 | 58 | 2 | 93 | 6 |
| Video Production | 737 | 62 | 8.41% | 66 | 5 | 0 | 43 | 1 | 6 | 0 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 0 |
| Latin Language | 756 | 63 | 8.33% | 65 | 16 | 4 | 10 | 2 | 32 | 10 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| Computer Graphics | 469 | 39 | 8.32% | 40 | 0 | 0 | 22 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 8 | 0 |
| Vi and Vim | 1,590 | 127 | 7.99% | 142 | 49 | 1 | 62 | 1 | 23 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 3 | 1 |
| Software Recommendations | 1,870 | 148 | 7.91% | 151 | 3 | 0 | 130 | 7 | 16 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Ebooks | 64 | 5 | 7.81% | 5 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Martial Arts | 169 | 13 | 7.69% | 13 | 4 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| Bioinformatics | 983 | 74 | 7.53% | 84 | 5 | 1 | 20 | 2 | 34 | 4 | 9 | 0 | 16 | 0 |
| Ask Patents | 293 | 21 | 7.17% | 22 | 0 | 0 | 18 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Quantum Computing | 2,532 | 166 | 6.56% | 172 | 31 | 1 | 59 | 2 | 56 | 2 | 18 | 1 | 8 | 0 |
| スタック・オーバーフロー | 3,758 | 243 | 6.47% | 245 | 11 | 0 | 174 | 22 | 51 | 3 | 6 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| Coffee | 93 | 6 | 6.45% | 6 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| Sustainable Living | 155 | 10 | 6.45% | 11 | 2 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Ethereum | 12,584 | 801 | 6.37% | 864 | 384 | 9 | 271 | 4 | 165 | 0 | 16 | 0 | 28 | 1 |
| Data Science | 6,675 | 411 | 6.16% | 470 | 24 | 0 | 242 | 1 | 136 | 1 | 42 | 0 | 26 | 0 |
| Iota | 33 | 2 | 6.06% | 3 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Hinduism | 1,937 | 117 | 6.04% | 121 | 69 | 0 | 33 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 17 | 0 |
| Ukrainian Language | 100 | 6 | 6.0% | 6 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Expatriates | 607 | 36 | 5.93% | 36 | 9 | 0 | 18 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Italian Language | 155 | 9 | 5.81% | 9 | 2 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3D Printing | 765 | 43 | 5.62% | 46 | 11 | 0 | 15 | 1 | 14 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Proof Assistants | 589 | 33 | 5.6% | 33 | 5 | 0 | 14 | 3 | 6 | 3 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| Reverse Engineering | 900 | 50 | 5.56% | 56 | 7 | 0 | 24 | 1 | 21 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Beer, Wine and Spirits | 39 | 2 | 5.13% | 3 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Esperanto Language | 45 | 2 | 4.44% | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Open Data | 390 | 17 | 4.36% | 21 | 2 | 0 | 12 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| SharePoint | 3,112 | 123 | 3.95% | 127 | 9 | 0 | 47 | 0 | 59 | 2 | 7 | 1 | 5 | 0 |
| Operations Research | 980 | 38 | 3.88% | 39 | 7 | 0 | 18 | 0 | 12 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| EOS.IO | 106 | 4 | 3.77% | 6 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Tezos | 322 | 11 | 3.42% | 11 | 6 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Tridion | 147 | 5 | 3.4% | 5 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Русский язык | 1,339 | 44 | 3.29% | 44 | 0 | 0 | 32 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 7 | 0 |
| Gardening and Landscaping | 902 | 28 | 3.1% | 28 | 2 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 16 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Cardano | 1,514 | 46 | 3.04% | 48 | 3 | 0 | 16 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 9 | 0 | 9 | 0 |
| Bioacoustics | 355 | 10 | 2.82% | 10 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Korean Language | 143 | 4 | 2.8% | 5 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Joomla | 439 | 12 | 2.73% | 13 | 1 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 7 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Emacs | 2,649 | 67 | 2.53% | 68 | 32 | 0 | 9 | 0 | 24 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| ExpressionEngine® Answers | 58 | 1 | 1.72% | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Magento | 5,612 | 43 | 0.77% | 55 | 14 | 0 | 16 | 0 | 23 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Tor | 251 | 1 | 0.4% | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Craft CMS | 761 | 3 | 0.39% | 4 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| elementary OS | 370 | 1 | 0.27% | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| CS50 | 782 | 2 | 0.26% | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

#### Notes

- This counts questions asked in 2022 and questions closed in 2022 - the AskedAndClosed and PctAskedAndClosed columns reflect questions that were *both* asked and closed in 2022, while the remaining columns total up all questions closed in 2022 - even those asked in prior years.
- Reopen numbers also include questions asked in years prior - but limit themselves to questions that were closed in 2022 and then also reopened in 2022.
- If a question was closed twice, it'll be counted twice.
- If a question was reopened twice, it'll be counted twice.

Comment: Thanks for the stats! I just noticed the table still uses "Too broad" instead of "Needs more focus" (updated [since 2020](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396754/2821954), also "Unclear" is now "Needs detail or clarity", though it's still similar wording). Is it deliberate? (also, apparently the 2021 stats still uses "Too broad" too)

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. Thanks for noticing it! If you do not mind, please go ahead and change the names. I used the ones from the previous year.

Comment: Where do migrations fit?

Comment: @Laurel I believe that they go to the "off-topic" category.

Comment: I think for next year it would be good to have a count of how many questions were successfully migrated. There's a big difference between questions that were closed (preventing any future answers) and questions that were closed but can (and maybe were) answered elsewhere. So far this year (ie, January) ELU for example had 60+ attempted migrations so the numbers are quite significant.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace comments asking to add the [featured] tag should feature some arguments... I like these posts, they're a nice set of statistics, but they're irrelevant to 99% of the visitors of the network. They've never been featured before, as far as I know.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT and Nicolas Chabanovsky - maybe add the fact that the names are changed in the Notes? It *does* seem like something potentially confusing if you're a newer user or from the future.