# 2023: a year in closing

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopened-questions

One of the traditions we have here on MSE as the calendar year changes, is to [post some statistics about post closures and reopenings across the network for the preceding calendar year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22year+in+closing%22+is%3Aquestion). In light of that tradition, please welcome stats that highlight how many questions were closed and reopened on all the sites in the Stack Exchange network in 2023.

[The same data in CSV format](https://gist.github.com/JNat/137b1f41c580611c3e4e40b70ac14e6e). [Data for 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386090/208518).

| Site Name | Asked | Asked And Closed | Pct Asked And Closed | All Closed | Duplicates Closed | Duplicates Reopened | OT Closed | OT Reopened | Unclear Closed | Unclear Reopened | Too Broad Closed | Too Broad Reopened | Opinion Based Closed | Opinion Based Reopened |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Interpersonal Skills | 245 | 184 | 75.10 | 184 | 1 | 0 | 125 | 2 | 44 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 11 | 0 |
| Network Engineering | 1783 | 1162 | 65.17 | 1169 | 59 | 2 | 933 | 7 | 149 | 18 | 8 | 1 | 20 | 0 |
| English Language and Usage | 5677 | 3618 | 63.73 | 4345 | 851 | 92 | 2414 | 226 | 549 | 41 | 93 | 16 | 438 | 56 |
| Stack Overflow em Português | 11615 | 7301 | 62.86 | 8245 | 181 | 9 | 6667 | 117 | 1191 | 26 | 117 | 3 | 89 | 2 |
| Web Applications | 2378 | 1242 | 52.23 | 2335 | 283 | 16 | 945 | 24 | 1045 | 86 | 48 | 8 | 14 | 2 |
| Chemistry | 4986 | 2474 | 49.62 | 2508 | 256 | 4 | 970 | 16 | 1074 | 32 | 150 | 9 | 58 | 0 |
| Medical Sciences | 591 | 287 | 48.56 | 308 | 0 | 0 | 263 | 15 | 19 | 0 | 9 | 0 | 17 | 0 |
| Meta Stack Exchange | 6559 | 3153 | 48.07 | 3401 | 693 | 43 | 2593 | 29 | 94 | 13 | 15 | 2 | 6 | 1 |
| Language Learning | 140 | 62 | 44.29 | 62 | 0 | 0 | 57 | 3 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Software Engineering | 2709 | 1183 | 43.67 | 1192 | 37 | 2 | 598 | 8 | 159 | 6 | 233 | 4 | 165 | 7 |
| Worldbuilding | 2554 | 1036 | 40.56 | 1055 | 126 | 12 | 347 | 24 | 224 | 14 | 203 | 23 | 155 | 7 |
| Information Security | 3532 | 1432 | 40.54 | 1487 | 223 | 7 | 933 | 10 | 210 | 13 | 25 | 1 | 96 | 2 |
| Skeptics | 607 | 233 | 38.39 | 233 | 10 | 0 | 163 | 15 | 30 | 12 | 18 | 3 | 12 | 1 |
| Physics | 25637 | 9834 | 38.36 | 10192 | 1662 | 93 | 5367 | 256 | 2395 | 213 | 472 | 52 | 296 | 22 |
| Project Management | 215 | 82 | 38.14 | 97 | 2 | 0 | 54 | 0 | 19 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 18 | 0 |
| History | 1124 | 422 | 37.54 | 429 | 11 | 1 | 192 | 7 | 104 | 13 | 39 | 3 | 83 | 7 |
| Psychology and Neuroscience | 629 | 233 | 37.04 | 244 | 24 | 1 | 134 | 4 | 23 | 1 | 30 | 2 | 33 | 1 |
| Anime and Manga | 455 | 163 | 35.82 | 167 | 22 | 1 | 112 | 6 | 11 | 0 | 9 | 0 | 13 | 0 |
| Arduino | 1942 | 662 | 34.09 | 732 | 59 | 2 | 295 | 7 | 305 | 10 | 50 | 0 | 23 | 3 |
| Sound Design | 309 | 101 | 32.69 | 114 | 3 | 0 | 94 | 1 | 10 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| The Workplace | 1381 | 441 | 31.93 | 442 | 29 | 3 | 305 | 6 | 35 | 1 | 11 | 1 | 62 | 4 |
| Quantitative Finance | 2215 | 700 | 31.60 | 725 | 98 | 3 | 411 | 12 | 106 | 3 | 46 | 3 | 64 | 1 |
| Webmasters | 1456 | 444 | 30.49 | 466 | 99 | 4 | 231 | 3 | 71 | 5 | 39 | 2 | 26 | 3 |
| Russian Language | 163 | 48 | 29.45 | 48 | 5 | 0 | 31 | 0 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| Music Fans | 178 | 51 | 28.65 | 268 | 0 |  | 264 |  | 1 |  | 0 |  | 3 |  |
| Politics | 2034 | 582 | 28.61 | 598 | 72 | 12 | 342 | 74 | 66 | 8 | 28 | 4 | 90 | 23 |
| Parenting | 224 | 62 | 27.68 | 64 | 8 | 1 | 26 | 1 | 8 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 21 | 0 |
| Code Review | 3101 | 840 | 27.09 | 856 | 6 | 0 | 781 | 35 | 66 | 4 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Linguistics | 1070 | 287 | 26.82 | 299 | 18 | 1 | 189 | 2 | 41 | 1 | 28 | 1 | 23 | 2 |
| Law | 4489 | 1190 | 26.51 | 1229 | 217 | 12 | 672 | 38 | 190 | 13 | 78 | 6 | 72 | 7 |
| Open Source | 424 | 111 | 26.18 | 115 | 58 | 1 | 47 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Drupal Answers | 2048 | 528 | 25.78 | 635 | 76 | 3 | 143 | 3 | 322 | 2 | 65 | 1 | 29 | 0 |
| Christianity | 1432 | 368 | 25.70 | 375 | 52 | 5 | 204 | 12 | 37 | 3 | 25 | 1 | 57 | 4 |
| Physical Fitness | 516 | 132 | 25.58 | 146 | 20 | 1 | 77 | 2 | 24 | 8 | 7 | 1 | 18 | 2 |
| Biblical Hermeneutics | 1557 | 397 | 25.50 | 414 | 72 | 0 | 226 | 10 | 70 | 3 | 10 | 0 | 36 | 1 |
| Geographic Information Systems | 13465 | 3374 | 25.06 | 3806 | 354 | 31 | 1554 | 121 | 993 | 85 | 691 | 93 | 214 | 3 |
| Biology | 1664 | 406 | 24.40 | 415 | 48 | 1 | 224 | 4 | 63 | 4 | 31 | 3 | 49 | 0 |
| Veganism and Vegetarianism | 70 | 17 | 24.29 | 17 | 1 |  | 5 |  | 6 |  | 1 |  | 4 |  |
| Lifehacks | 190 | 46 | 24.21 | 49 | 3 | 0 | 43 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Electrical Engineering | 20655 | 4894 | 23.69 | 4976 | 361 | 16 | 1905 | 77 | 1941 | 129 | 589 | 30 | 180 | 10 |
| Artificial Intelligence | 2902 | 682 | 23.50 | 696 | 24 | 0 | 346 | 0 | 174 | 1 | 99 | 1 | 53 | 1 |
| Prog Language Design & Implementation | 767 | 180 | 23.47 | 180 | 20 | 6 | 58 | 15 | 40 | 10 | 42 | 19 | 20 | 6 |
| Academia | 5169 | 1208 | 23.37 | 1234 | 296 | 6 | 760 | 15 | 88 | 3 | 34 | 2 | 56 | 4 |
| Code Golf | 724 | 167 | 23.07 | 186 | 34 | 7 | 84 | 2 | 67 | 17 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Seasoned Advice | 1087 | 250 | 23.00 | 261 | 107 | 2 | 64 | 4 | 40 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 45 | 4 |
| Mathematics | 128443 | 29504 | 22.97 | 31037 | 6590 | 167 | 18851 | 570 | 4721 | 128 | 624 | 39 | 251 | 10 |
| Computer Science Educators | 118 | 27 | 22.88 | 27 | 0 | 0 | 24 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| GenAI | 268 | 61 | 22.76 | 61 | 2 | 0 | 33 | 1 | 13 | 1 | 12 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| Music: Practice and Theory | 1777 | 401 | 22.57 | 432 | 131 | 8 | 192 | 2 | 46 | 1 | 19 | 0 | 44 | 1 |
| Cross Validated | 20851 | 4689 | 22.49 | 5371 | 945 | 48 | 2042 | 77 | 2029 | 142 | 292 | 23 | 63 | 5 |
| User Experience | 1254 | 278 | 22.17 | 316 | 14 | 0 | 137 | 1 | 82 | 1 | 18 | 0 | 65 | 1 |
| Sports | 325 | 72 | 22.15 | 74 | 15 | 0 | 28 | 1 | 8 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 19 | 0 |
| Cryptography | 2504 | 552 | 22.04 | 570 | 78 | 8 | 339 | 21 | 105 | 10 | 17 | 1 | 31 | 1 |
| Movies and TV | 1067 | 235 | 22.02 | 238 | 15 | 0 | 138 | 1 | 35 | 4 | 13 | 3 | 37 | 5 |
| Travel | 2964 | 647 | 21.83 | 864 | 319 | 14 | 378 | 8 | 107 | 10 | 19 | 3 | 41 | 7 |
| Home Improvement | 10574 | 2300 | 21.75 | 2535 | 292 | 16 | 840 | 27 | 805 | 45 | 236 | 15 | 362 | 11 |
| Sitecore | 1329 | 286 | 21.52 | 291 | 78 | 4 | 59 | 2 | 127 | 10 | 15 | 0 | 12 | 0 |
| Hardware Recommendations | 508 | 108 | 21.26 | 118 | 2 | 0 | 94 | 2 | 14 | 2 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| Pets | 413 | 86 | 20.82 | 88 | 33 | 0 | 35 | 0 | 13 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| Space Exploration | 1056 | 215 | 20.36 | 226 | 61 | 0 | 60 | 6 | 60 | 5 | 27 | 3 | 18 | 2 |
| Role-playing Games | 1946 | 394 | 20.25 | 422 | 181 | 38 | 41 | 3 | 92 | 26 | 35 | 7 | 73 | 10 |
| Freelancing | 79 | 16 | 20.25 | 16 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| Mathematica | 6800 | 1365 | 20.07 | 1450 | 237 | 4 | 955 | 7 | 227 | 3 | 19 | 1 | 12 | 1 |
| Ask Different | 7040 | 1388 | 19.72 | 1582 | 627 | 37 | 399 | 29 | 404 | 59 | 93 | 20 | 59 | 3 |
| Genealogy and Family History | 133 | 26 | 19.55 | 26 | 6 |  | 9 |  | 10 |  | 1 |  | 0 |  |
| Android Enthusiasts | 2908 | 548 | 18.84 | 845 | 263 | 2 | 400 | 18 | 139 | 10 | 28 | 2 | 15 | 1 |
| Mythology and Folklore | 101 | 19 | 18.81 | 20 | 3 |  | 4 |  | 8 |  | 5 |  | 0 |  |
| WordPress Development | 4806 | 885 | 18.41 | 957 | 15 | 0 | 841 | 5 | 45 | 1 | 32 | 1 | 24 | 0 |
| Bitcoin | 2294 | 419 | 18.27 | 455 | 165 | 3 | 183 | 3 | 84 | 0 | 10 | 1 | 13 | 1 |
| Mi Yodeya | 3291 | 598 | 18.17 | 613 | 248 | 7 | 208 | 12 | 95 | 10 | 25 | 6 | 37 | 4 |
| Arqade | 2259 | 408 | 18.06 | 510 | 176 | 5 | 146 | 4 | 146 | 1 | 17 | 2 | 25 | 2 |
| Japanese Language | 2055 | 369 | 17.96 | 375 | 165 | 6 | 168 | 4 | 25 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 13 | 0 |
| Photography | 831 | 149 | 17.93 | 157 | 44 | 2 | 74 | 2 | 25 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 10 | 0 |
| Martial Arts | 67 | 12 | 17.91 | 13 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 4 | 2 |
| Stack Overflow | 1489399 | 266207 | 17.87 | 287979 | 80073 | 2640 | 111498 | 1633 | 53724 | 941 | 31277 | 373 | 11407 | 194 |
| English Language Learners | 6615 | 1163 | 17.58 | 1244 | 220 | 0 | 806 | 21 | 143 | 5 | 22 | 0 | 53 | 2 |
| Matter Modeling | 1046 | 182 | 17.40 | 359 | 14 | 0 | 313 | 0 | 27 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| The Great Outdoors | 213 | 37 | 17.37 | 40 | 6 | 0 | 17 | 2 | 13 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Retrocomputing | 655 | 113 | 17.25 | 118 | 10 | 4 | 65 | 3 | 33 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 8 | 2 |
| Bricks | 337 | 58 | 17.21 | 60 | 28 | 1 | 9 | 0 | 18 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| Chess | 809 | 138 | 17.06 | 146 | 36 | 0 | 14 | 2 | 35 | 1 | 19 | 5 | 42 | 5 |
| Arts and Crafts | 223 | 38 | 17.04 | 42 | 2 | 0 | 12 | 0 | 17 | 0 | 6 | 2 | 5 | 0 |
| Science Fiction and Fantasy | 4386 | 746 | 17.01 | 822 | 306 | 21 | 254 | 21 | 109 | 14 | 39 | 4 | 114 | 8 |
| Blender | 15262 | 2525 | 16.54 | 2627 | 783 | 45 | 665 | 21 | 976 | 97 | 127 | 12 | 76 | 3 |
| Monero | 194 | 32 | 16.49 | 32 | 27 |  | 5 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  |
| Raspberry Pi | 2155 | 352 | 16.33 | 368 | 24 | 0 | 222 | 4 | 79 | 2 | 15 | 0 | 28 | 0 |
| MathOverflow | 14377 | 2343 | 16.30 | 2366 | 47 | 1 | 2103 | 16 | 167 | 0 | 23 | 1 | 26 | 6 |
| Writing | 858 | 139 | 16.20 | 142 | 16 | 0 | 96 | 0 | 14 | 0 | 4 | 1 | 12 | 0 |
| Aviation | 2198 | 355 | 16.15 | 359 | 109 | 4 | 94 | 2 | 99 | 8 | 30 | 2 | 27 | 3 |
| Amateur Radio | 313 | 50 | 15.97 | 50 | 3 | 0 | 28 | 1 | 14 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| Board and Card Games | 534 | 85 | 15.92 | 92 | 40 | 3 | 13 | 2 | 18 | 3 | 10 | 1 | 11 | 0 |
| Software Quality Assurance and Testing | 503 | 80 | 15.90 | 88 | 6 |  | 24 |  | 35 |  | 6 |  | 17 |  |
| Homebrewing | 57 | 9 | 15.79 | 9 | 0 |  | 9 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  |
| Philosophy | 3156 | 498 | 15.78 | 511 | 37 | 2 | 223 | 8 | 137 | 5 | 26 | 2 | 88 | 5 |
| Puzzling | 1747 | 272 | 15.57 | 285 | 42 | 3 | 205 | 27 | 34 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Islam | 1455 | 226 | 15.53 | 242 | 108 | 0 | 59 | 0 | 38 | 1 | 16 | 0 | 21 | 0 |
| Super User | 31276 | 4831 | 15.45 | 4927 | 745 | 25 | 2435 | 43 | 1369 | 41 | 128 | 5 | 250 | 7 |
| TeX - LaTeX | 16486 | 2513 | 15.24 | 3074 | 1333 | 36 | 455 | 6 | 1189 | 70 | 56 | 1 | 41 | 2 |
| Stack Overflow на русском | 46479 | 7011 | 15.08 | 7255 | 1223 | 34 | 3212 | 70 | 1730 | 23 | 375 | 7 | 715 | 3 |
| Stack Overflow en español | 20124 | 2831 | 14.07 | 3027 | 205 | 5 | 941 | 18 | 1361 | 14 | 192 | 1 | 328 | 7 |
| Coffee | 64 | 9 | 14.06 | 11 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| Mathematics Educators | 330 | 46 | 13.94 | 48 | 2 | 0 | 35 | 2 | 7 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Ask Ubuntu | 27986 | 3858 | 13.79 | 4226 | 1748 | 44 | 1656 | 18 | 642 | 21 | 69 | 3 | 111 | 7 |
| Spanish Language | 365 | 50 | 13.70 | 57 | 12 | 0 | 33 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| German Language | 1165 | 156 | 13.39 | 159 | 49 | 0 | 66 | 2 | 36 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Earth Science | 551 | 73 | 13.25 | 73 | 13 | 0 | 34 | 2 | 17 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| Personal Finance and Money | 2254 | 293 | 13.00 | 300 | 64 | 3 | 155 | 0 | 31 | 1 | 9 | 0 | 41 | 0 |
| History of Science and Mathematics | 497 | 59 | 11.87 | 59 | 5 |  | 40 |  | 6 |  | 4 |  | 4 |  |
| Poker | 98 | 11 | 11.22 | 14 | 8 |  | 1 |  | 3 |  | 0 |  | 2 |  |
| Astronomy | 1398 | 152 | 10.87 | 156 | 38 | 1 | 43 | 0 | 47 | 0 | 14 | 0 | 14 | 0 |
| Salesforce | 11633 | 1257 | 10.81 | 1293 | 296 | 4 | 748 | 2 | 227 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 19 | 0 |
| Woodworking | 340 | 36 | 10.59 | 36 | 4 |  | 14 |  | 11 |  | 5 |  | 2 |  |
| Game Development | 2581 | 271 | 10.50 | 293 | 51 | 2 | 144 | 7 | 52 | 1 | 25 | 2 | 21 | 0 |
| Graphic Design | 1445 | 147 | 10.17 | 150 | 36 | 2 | 65 | 0 | 13 | 0 | 20 | 0 | 16 | 0 |
| Engineering | 2054 | 207 | 10.08 | 211 | 8 | 0 | 83 | 0 | 84 | 2 | 25 | 0 | 11 | 0 |
| Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair | 1545 | 150 | 9.71 | 153 | 12 | 1 | 82 | 1 | 40 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 13 | 0 |
| Server Fault | 17674 | 1630 | 9.22 | 1660 | 119 | 1 | 1245 | 5 | 217 | 0 | 33 | 0 | 46 | 1 |
| Literature | 859 | 79 | 9.20 | 81 | 7 | 0 | 38 | 3 | 18 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 11 | 0 |
| Ukrainian Language | 120 | 11 | 9.17 | 12 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Database Administrators | 6412 | 586 | 9.14 | 930 | 139 | 5 | 370 | 4 | 392 | 9 | 13 | 0 | 16 | 1 |
| Latin Language | 785 | 69 | 8.79 | 70 | 22 | 3 | 21 | 5 | 22 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Computer Science | 3398 | 298 | 8.77 | 302 | 52 | 1 | 153 | 2 | 60 | 4 | 29 | 2 | 8 | 0 |
| Stack Apps | 539 | 47 | 8.72 | 63 | 12 | 1 | 42 | 1 | 8 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| DevOps | 976 | 84 | 8.61 | 88 | 1 | 0 | 43 | 0 | 26 | 1 | 8 | 0 | 10 | 0 |
| Ask Patents | 202 | 17 | 8.42 | 17 | 0 |  | 15 |  | 2 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  |
| French Language | 754 | 63 | 8.36 | 66 | 27 | 2 | 29 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| Beer, Wine and Spirits | 36 | 3 | 8.33 | 3 | 1 |  | 2 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  |
| Robotics | 2547 | 206 | 8.09 | 210 | 12 | 0 | 53 | 0 | 81 | 6 | 15 | 1 | 49 | 1 |
| Solana | 1747 | 141 | 8.07 | 228 | 29 |  | 79 |  | 101 |  | 9 |  | 10 |  |
| Economics | 1810 | 143 | 7.90 | 146 | 15 | 0 | 84 | 2 | 21 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 18 | 0 |
| Drones and Model Aircraft | 152 | 12 | 7.89 | 12 | 1 |  | 2 |  | 6 |  | 2 |  | 1 |  |
| Internet of Things | 153 | 12 | 7.84 | 16 | 0 |  | 4 |  | 4 |  | 5 |  | 3 |  |
| Signal Processing | 2241 | 171 | 7.63 | 177 | 47 | 4 | 76 | 4 | 45 | 4 | 8 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Constructed Languages | 106 | 8 | 7.55 | 8 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Unix and Linux | 16104 | 1211 | 7.52 | 1324 | 551 | 22 | 305 | 3 | 336 | 5 | 47 | 1 | 85 | 0 |
| Bicycles | 1436 | 108 | 7.52 | 121 | 21 | 0 | 35 | 0 | 54 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| Computational Science | 802 | 60 | 7.48 | 60 | 0 |  | 32 |  | 25 |  | 2 |  | 1 |  |
| Buddhism | 426 | 31 | 7.28 | 31 | 7 | 1 | 12 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| Gardening and Landscaping | 940 | 67 | 7.13 | 71 | 16 | 1 | 14 | 0 | 28 | 2 | 10 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| Portuguese Language | 122 | 8 | 6.56 | 8 | 4 |  | 1 |  | 2 |  | 1 |  | 0 |  |
| Computer Graphics | 381 | 25 | 6.56 | 28 | 0 |  | 19 |  | 7 |  | 0 |  | 2 |  |
| Quantum Computing | 2536 | 164 | 6.47 | 171 | 51 | 3 | 49 | 0 | 56 | 0 | 8 | 1 | 7 | 0 |
| スタック・オーバーフロー | 2372 | 152 | 6.41 | 155 | 11 | 0 | 107 | 8 | 26 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 7 | 0 |
| Hinduism | 1792 | 112 | 6.25 | 121 | 54 | 1 | 40 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 5 | 1 | 19 | 1 |
| 3D Printing | 752 | 47 | 6.25 | 50 | 10 | 1 | 15 | 1 | 17 | 2 | 4 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Vi and Vim | 1396 | 86 | 6.16 | 96 | 21 | 2 | 50 | 0 | 14 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 7 | 0 |
| Open Data | 320 | 19 | 5.94 | 21 | 2 |  | 11 |  | 8 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  |
| Software Recommendations | 1545 | 90 | 5.83 | 95 | 3 | 0 | 63 | 0 | 25 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Ethereum | 7148 | 411 | 5.75 | 441 | 159 | 2 | 160 | 2 | 111 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 7 | 0 |
| Theoretical Computer Science | 866 | 48 | 5.54 | 50 | 1 |  | 47 |  | 1 |  | 0 |  | 1 |  |
| Italian Language | 149 | 8 | 5.37 | 8 | 2 |  | 5 |  | 1 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  |
| Ebooks | 77 | 4 | 5.19 | 4 | 0 |  | 3 |  | 0 |  | 1 |  | 0 |  |
| Video Production | 660 | 34 | 5.15 | 39 | 2 |  | 26 |  | 8 |  | 2 |  | 1 |  |
| SharePoint | 2689 | 136 | 5.06 | 138 | 12 | 0 | 37 | 1 | 69 | 9 | 16 | 2 | 4 | 0 |
| Русский язык | 1884 | 95 | 5.04 | 97 | 11 | 0 | 61 | 4 | 14 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| Reverse Engineering | 749 | 37 | 4.94 | 42 | 3 |  | 21 |  | 16 |  | 1 |  | 1 |  |
| Sustainable Living | 110 | 5 | 4.55 | 5 | 0 |  | 2 |  | 3 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  |
| Emacs | 2425 | 107 | 4.41 | 128 | 62 | 2 | 15 | 0 | 35 | 1 | 8 | 0 | 8 | 1 |
| Bioinformatics | 861 | 35 | 4.07 | 38 | 3 | 0 | 10 | 1 | 10 | 0 | 10 | 1 | 5 | 1 |
| Expatriates | 496 | 20 | 4.03 | 22 | 8 |  | 7 |  | 2 |  | 0 |  | 5 |  |
| Data Science | 4155 | 166 | 4.00 | 180 | 12 |  | 84 |  | 49 |  | 16 |  | 19 |  |
| Community Building | 55 | 2 | 3.64 | 2 | 0 |  | 1 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  | 1 |  |
| Chinese Language and Usage | 812 | 29 | 3.57 | 35 | 12 | 0 | 12 | 1 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Substrate and Polkadot | 2040 | 71 | 3.48 | 77 | 29 |  | 15 |  | 24 |  | 6 |  | 3 |  |
| Stellar | 67 | 2 | 2.99 | 3 | 0 |  | 0 |  | 1 |  | 1 |  | 1 |  |
| Operations Research | 852 | 25 | 2.93 | 27 | 10 |  | 10 |  | 6 |  | 0 |  | 1 |  |
| Korean Language | 137 | 4 | 2.92 | 6 | 0 |  | 3 |  | 2 |  | 0 |  | 1 |  |
| elementary OS | 145 | 4 | 2.76 | 6 | 0 |  | 4 |  | 2 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  |
| Joomla | 436 | 12 | 2.75 | 12 | 2 |  | 7 |  | 3 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  |
| Proof Assistants | 341 | 9 | 2.64 | 9 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Craft CMS | 524 | 13 | 2.48 | 13 | 2 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Esperanto Language | 51 | 1 | 1.96 | 2 | 0 |  | 1 |  | 1 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  |
| Tor | 206 | 4 | 1.94 | 6 | 2 |  | 0 |  | 1 |  | 0 |  | 3 |  |
| Magento | 3463 | 53 | 1.53 | 58 | 14 |  | 13 |  | 23 |  | 2 |  | 6 |  |
| CS50 | 721 | 8 | 1.11 | 13 | 2 |  | 3 |  | 7 |  | 1 |  | 0 |  |
| Tezos | 317 | 3 | 0.95 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Bioacoustics | 113 | 1 | 0.88 | 1 | 1 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  |
| Cardano | 342 | 2 | 0.58 | 10 | 2 |  | 3 |  | 3 |  | 2 |  | 0 |  |
| CiviCRM | 954 | 1 | 0.10 | 1 | 0 |  | 1 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  |

#### Notes

- This counts questions asked in 2023 and questions closed in 2023 - the AskedAndClosed and PctAskedAndClosed columns reflect questions that were *both* asked and closed in 2023, while the remaining columns total up all questions closed in 2023 - even those asked in prior years.
- Reopen numbers also include questions asked in years prior - but are limited to questions that were closed in 2023 and then also reopened in 2023.
- If a question was closed twice, it'll be counted twice.
- If a question was reopened twice, it'll be counted twice.

Comment: Okay, IPS won. Congrats to them. At least Stack Apps didn't come last ...

Comment: What do the empty cells mean?

Comment: @ElementsInSpace reminds me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnXpN.jpg)

Comment: The number of columns is already troublesome (perhaps split it up into several tables?), but I expected 'deleted' columns: Some of: number of deleted posts, number of deleted questions, number of deleted answers, percentage deleted posts, and percentage automatically deleted (in contrast to by some manual (human) process).

Comment: does the order in which the sites appear mean anything?

Comment: @user13267 they seem to be sorted by closure %

Comment: A couple of comments: the "Beer, Wine and Spirits" row is broken in the CSV, since a comma is included in the name of the site (last year it was wrapped in quotes). Generally, it would be neat to have an "All Reopened" and "Percent Reopened" to go along with the "Percent Asked and Closed" column, though I was able to do so myself with the raw data (which is much appreciated). Saw some interesting things when looking at it that way.