# 2023: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It’s that time of the year again! As we wave goodbye to last year and welcome the new one, we have [a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the preceding calendar year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

As most of you here might be aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

That doesn't eliminate the need for having [moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks — folks like you. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference in ensuring Stack Exchange sites remain a valuable source of high-quality content on the web.

So as we say goodbye to 2023 (and January 2024… ahem) and move into 2024, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some [*exciting* stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmN7M.gif). Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Meta Stack Exchange over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community User¹ | Community² |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 9 | 0 | 0 |
| Answer flags handled | 1,422 | 1,648 | 0 |
| Answers flagged | 251 | 270 | 2,544 |
| Bounties canceled | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Comment flags handled | 3,367 | 687 | 49 |
| Comments deleted⁸ | 5,558 | 86 | 2,939 |
| Comments flagged | 862 | 42 | 3,201 |
| Comments undeleted | 126 | 0 | 0 |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 18 | 0 | 0 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 28 | 0 |
| Posts deleted⁷ | 1,931 | 3,120 | 1,089 |
| Posts locked | 43 | 2,084 | 0 |
| Posts undeleted | 125 | 1 | 147 |
| Posts unlocked | 9 | 18 | 0 |
| Question flags handled⁶ | 3,125 | 9,233 | 0 |
| Questions closed | 1,626 | 1,684 | 91 |
| Questions flagged⁶ | 672 | 260 | 11,429 |
| Questions merged | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| Questions migrated | 44 | 0 | 0 |
| Questions protected | 3 | 86 | 25 |
| Questions reopened | 44 | 52 | 11 |
| Questions unprotected | 3 | 0 | 5 |
| Revisions redacted | 206 | 0 | 0 |
| Tag highlight language set | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms created | 22 | 0 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 14 | 0 | 2 |
| Tags merged | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Close votes" queue | 135 | 0 | 3,106 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "First answers" queue | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "First questions" queue | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Late answers" queue | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Low quality posts" queue | 54 | 0 | 859 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Reopen votes" queue | 31 | 0 | 618 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Suggested edits" queue | 63 | 105 | 1,225 |
| Tasks reviewed⁵: "Triage" queue | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| User banned from review | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| User review-bans lifted early | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| User suspensions lifted early | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Users contacted | 163 | 0 | 0 |
| Users deleted | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| Users destroyed⁴ | 428 | 0 | 0 |
| Users suspended³ | 124 | 577 | 0 |

#### Footnotes

¹ This refers to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² This refers to [the membership of Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).

³ The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

⁴ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁵ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁶ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes). The community² can handle these flags by at least one person voting to close a question that has a close flag.

⁷ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁸ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: [2022: a year in moderation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386095/2022-a-year-in-moderation)
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222023%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396299/208518)

Wishing everyone a happy 2024! ^_^

Comment: For comments deleted by the Community user, does that refer to comments deleted by users who later deleted their accounts?

Comment: no totals column?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog No, comments deleted by users who later deleted their accounts are counted under "Community".

Comment: @AdamLear Ah, so then why do comments get deleted by the Community user? Also, when an automatic duplicate comment is automatically deleted as a result of the question being closed as a duplicate, which column is it counted in?

Comment: @Sonic  It looks like your edit changed “Wanna” to “Want to”.  1. Why did you make this edit?  2. Why does the revision page say “added 43 characters in body”?

Comment: @ElementsInSpace I have no idea why it says I added 43 characters to the body. I made the edit because it didn't seem proper to me to use an extremely informal English word in what's meant to be a formal post.

Comment: @Sonic A touch of informality (such as the occasional “y'all”, “ahem”, “^_^”, etc.) make this post more conversational/human, and less dry/boring.  It’s a deliberate choice of writing style that actually improves the readability of this post.

Comment: @ElementsInSpace the diff works in an odd way, I can look it up later and post in chat but the TL;DR is something about checking whole paragraph and counting the difference by words or something like that. Anyway it's not a bug.

Answer (score 6):

### Rows for "questions closed" and "questions reopened" are incorrect/misleading

Shortly after these posts were published on all sites, there was some [confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396358/377214) as to why the Community user is shown as having reopened many questions, generally more than what the community reopened. The Community user cannot itself reopen questions - the only case where it would be shown as a reopen voter is [if a user who's cast a *pending* vote to reopen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228455/377214) later has their account removed.

Eventually, after some sleuthing, we discovered that the columns for that row are based on the (individual) user listed in the history event in each question. When more than one user is involved in reopening a question and a moderator isn't involved, the system will list the Community user in the history event. Based on fairly obvious conjecture (the community most definitely closed more than 91 questions here on this site, what with the large amount of blatantly off-topic posts coming in daily), it appears the same is true for the closed questions row. This means that:

- The "Moderators" column shows questions where a moderator closed or reopened. (This is the only column that is correct.)
- The "Community user" column shows questions where the community closed or reopened without any type of binding vote, questions where a gold-badge user bindingly closed or reopened and other users had also cast votes, and (for the closed questions row only) where the Community user actually cast a binding vote in response to the author approving a proposed duplicate.
- The "Community" column shows questions where a gold-badge user bindingly closed or reopened the question without anyone else voting.

The latter two columns, as you can see, don't conform to the actual definitions. In particular, the way it should be like is as follows:

- The "Community user" column in the closed questions row should only list cases where the author approved a pending duplicate vote or flag. For the reopen questions row, it should be zero since the bot cannot reopen questions.
- The "Community" column should list all closures and reopenings done without binding votes or with binding votes from gold-badge users.

Can these fixes be deployed on all sites?

Comment: see also: https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/1816814/close-by-community?opt.textResults=true