# Will we get moderation statistics published on all sites for 2021?

Tags: discussion, moderation, per-site-meta, statistics

Since 2018, at the beginning of every new year, the team has posted annual moderation statistics on all meta sites on the network. These included a full table of how many of which moderation actions were taken by the community and site moderators across all categories of moderation (e.g. review tasks reviewed, posts curated, users suspended/deleted, etc.) on the main site. This tradition [started in 2016 on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340815/2016-a-year-in-moderation), and since 2018 it's happened on all sites on the network every year.

I [asked about this last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356688/377214), and based on the community responses I got then, it's clear that many value these posts quite highly as they help to gauge the health of the site and which parts need work. The staff response to it also agrees that these statistics were useful, but that they'd prefer to move to real-time statistics. A [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356688/will-yearly-moderation-statistics-be-published-on-all-sites-this-year-and-futur#comment1199136_359235) from the same staff member who answered states that if that gets off the ground, then 2020 will probably be the last year for which they'll publish these posts. However, nothing seems to have progressed about it since then, so publishing these posts is still important in my opinion.

To ask the same question I asked last year: will these posts be published on all sites this year? The prior question was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), so I'm asking this again for this year. (The staff member who originally took up the initiative no longer works for Stack Exchange, so will another current staff take it up?)

It'd also be nice if the annual [year in closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359735/2020-a-year-in-closing) post here were published for 2021 as well. Also, when it comes to the moderation stats table for this site, please don't forget my [suggestion from last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359821/377214) to separate out columns for actions taken by local moderators vs. SE employees: I hope that the [note made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359769/2020-a-year-in-moderation?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1201717_359821) wasn't lost.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, stats for 2021 will be posted just like last year. Like I mentioned at the bottom of last year's posts, Brian worked on making using the script much more user friendly, so I should be able to run everything on my own. As far as I know there haven't been any developments to make these stats available in a more real-time fashion.

Your note about splitting actions taken by local mods vs. staff was not lost, but like I mentioned then it is a non-trivial amount of work and it wasn't prioritized this year.

As with last year, you can expect a new "a year in closing" post too, posted by Nicolas.

Comment: Wondering if they'll be published for 2022 as well. Would be nice if the team got to updating the scripts used to generate those posts so they can be posted within 6-8 days of the year starting.

Comment: they will be posted for 2022, yes

Comment: Thanks! To be clear, it also includes the overall "year in closing" post here, right?

Comment: Yes, @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog. "Year in closing" posts may go out sooner than "year in moderation" posts, since changes to the latter's script may not be ready in the very early days of January and are actively being worked on.

Comment: Checking in to make sure this wasn't forgotten. We already have some people [clamoring](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385912/will-we-get-a-2022-a-year-in-moderation-closing-post-this-year).

Comment: It wasn't forgotten, no.

Comment: @Sonic Andrew isn't one to clamor, he's asking nicely. :-D

Comment: Annual reminder for 2023 :)

Comment: yes, it's in my backlog @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog

Answer (score 6):

I very much want the statistics to be published at the end of the year as usual.

I spent the whole year curating content looking forward to seeing the numbers crunched; how my personal contribution fits into the bigger picture and how the communities did by volume of work.

I understand the company is planning to build the statistics into the system and I'm looking forward to that. But breaking with the yearly publication of the stats before there's an adequate substitute would be a major disappointment.