# Will we get a "2022: a year in moderation & closing" post this year?

Tags: support, status-completed, moderators, statistics

For the last year (2021) stats, the network-wide "a year in closing" and per-site "a year in moderation" posts were posted on the 3rd and 12th of January 2022:

- [2021: a year in closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374784/2021-a-year-in-closing) (3rd)
- [2021: a year in moderation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375072/2021-a-year-in-moderation) (12th)

The previous year was posted on the 19th: [2020: a year in moderation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359769/2020-a-year-in-moderation).

Today is already the second half of January 2023. Will the statistics for 2022 be published?

---

*Note: I noticed the general Q&A [Will yearly moderation statistics be published on all sites this year, and future years?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356688/will-yearly-moderation-statistics-be-published-on-all-sites-this-year-and-futur?rq=1), but this question is specific for this (last?) year.*

Comment: 19, 12, 3 --> 26 (So in a week.)

Comment: I was [told so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371916/will-we-get-moderation-statistics-published-on-all-sites-for-2021#comment1280280_372910).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog oof thanks, didn't expect to check on that question.

Comment: For the past two years (the two since Shog9, the originator of the yearly tradition, ceased working for SE), I had a tradition of posting an annual reminder on November 16. I [asked whether I should do so this year in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/2022-moderation-stats-post) and was told not to do so by a moderator and to wait until February before posting a reminder. They also said that despite my prior question (linked at the bottom) being practically about 2020 stats, it's still technically about all future years so in their view this would be a duplicate.

Comment: Well, I'm actually okay with this being closed as a dupe of the canonical. It's just, I need the 2022 stat for further meta discussion, so either I have to wait or just refer to the 2021 one :)

Comment: JNat [confirmed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371916/will-we-get-moderation-statistics-published-on-all-sites-for-2021/372910?noredirect=1#comment1286818_372910) that it wasn't forgotten.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is still something we're planning to do, yes.

Last year some folks provided feedback about other stuff they thought should be included, or other minor tweaks the script could use. I'd left a reminder for myself to look into those, and get them worked on at some point around September-ish, but... only ended up requesting the devs look at it in late November or so — y'know, just before folks have a lot of work, we have a code freeze, and many people have time off scheduled. So, my bad! But the script that generates these stats is currently being worked on, and hopefully I can post them Soon™.

[As with previous years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374784/208518), you can also expect a "year in closing" post by Nicolas this year.

Comment: Thanks JNat! I'll check back in 6 to 8 weeks.