# 2020: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, meta, moderation, statistics

As we say goodbye to the old year and welcome the new one, we have [a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the past 12 months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

As most of you here are aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

That doesn't eliminate the need for having [moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference.

So as we welcome 2021, and in keeping with tradition, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some [*exciting* stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU1Al.jpg). Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Meta Stack Exchange over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Users suspended² | 115 | 216 |
| Users destroyed³ | 1,510 | 0 |
| Users deleted | 23 | 0 |
| Users contacted | 156 | 1 |
| User suspensions lifted early | 2 | 0 |
| User review-bans lifted early | 2 | 0 |
| User banned from review | 3 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue | 33 | 2,149 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue | 11 | 2,232 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue | 10 | 1,252 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue | 11 | 6,061 |
| Tags merged | 6 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 4 | 7 |
| Tag synonyms created | 10 | 1 |
| Revisions redacted | 11 | 0 |
| Questions unprotected | 5 | 24 |
| Questions reopened | 51 | 135 |
| Questions protected | 2 | 125 |
| Questions migrated | 59 | 0 |
| Questions merged | 1 | 0 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 409 | 18,804 |
| Questions closed | 1,903 | 4,344 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 3,407 | 15,799 |
| Posts unlocked | 14 | 28 |
| Posts undeleted | 53 | 241 |
| Posts locked | 57 | 2,010 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 2,823 | 6,792 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 67 |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 9 | 0 |
| Comments undeleted | 110 | 0 |
| Comments flagged | 37 | 4,362 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 7,284 | 5,668 |
| Comment flags handled | 3,356 | 1,053 |
| Bounties canceled | 4 | 0 |
| Answers flagged | 180 | 3,415 |
| Answer flags handled | 1,555 | 2,055 |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 28 | 0 |

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: [2019: a year in moderation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341369/2019-a-year-in-moderation)
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222020%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359735/208518)

A big thank you to [Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9) for writing the queries and script to facilitate fetching and posting this data to all the sites in the network, and to [Brian](https://stackexchange.com/users/459488/brian-nickel) for the subsequent work making the whole thing more user friendly.

Wishing everyone a happy 2021!

Comment: How did the community contact 1 user?

Comment: Hmm. I am curious too, but not enough to dig through all the mod messages 

Comment: The amount of flags handled almost equals the amount of flags raised. I don't expect them to be 100% the same due to carry over from 2019 and to 2021. But seeing that they are so close does that mean that no flags aged away, or is that captured as being handled by the community user?

Comment: @double-beep I'm pretty sure it's a mod-message Robert Cartaino sent before being fired, so it's now counted as being from "the membership of Meta Stack Exchange without diamonds next to their names".

Comment: @Luuklag I think aged away flags are dismissed by the Community user

Answer (score 13):

As this site is the network meta, a large portion of the moderator actions here aren't performed by local moderators, but by Stack Exchange employees exercising their staff moderator privileges. In fact, between April 2014 and November 2018, this site had no moderators, with the only moderators being SE staff.

I'm curious to know the proportion today of moderator actions which are performed by local moderators, as opposed to SE employees.

When it comes to the moderator-performed actions in the table, **can we please get a breakdown of the number of actions performed by local moderators, and the number of actions performed by Stack Exchange staff**? In other words, I'd like to see the "Moderators" column broken down into "Local moderators" and "SE staff".

Comment: Seeing that the group of local moderators is only 2 IIRC that shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: 3 actually. You forgot one

Comment: I thought all moderators on all other Stack Exchange were automatically moderators on MSE. Was that never the case?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q No, this hasn't been the case since the Meta Stack Overflow-Meta Stack Exchange split. After that, only SE staff were moderators (until November 2018, when this site got its own, separate team of moderators).

Comment: That's just something I have been saying for years *should* happen, @P.Mort; not something that ever actually *did* happen.

Comment: @CodyGray Too bad you weren't a mod in the pre-split days. Back then, all Trilogy moderators had moderator access here.

Comment: I was, actually, just not on Stack Overflow. And I don't remember having mod access on MSO. Perhaps it was something implemented between the time that I stopped being a mod on Philosophy and the time of the Great Meta Schism? The former would have been around 2011-12?

Comment: @CodyGray No, only the Trilogy moderators (Stack Overflow, Super User, and Server Fault) ever had mod access here during that time.

Comment: Oh, that's right. I remember that now. Thanks for the reminder! Your memory is impressive.

Comment: I checked with Brian, and making this split would be a non-trivial amount of work. I can't guarantee we'll be doing it for 2020's stats, but I'll make a note to try to get it prioritized for 2021's stats.