# Where can I download previous SE database snapshots?

Tags: support, data-dump, data-analysis

I'm aware I can download the entire anonymized Stack Exchange databases from https://archive.org/details/stackexchange

But from what I can see, I can only download the latest snapshot, updated every three months (according to [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)).

But is there a way to download the previous snapshots?

Specifically, I would need those data to extract trends by studying how questions' view count evolves.

Comment: FYI [Hosting all Stack Exchange data dumps on archive.org](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306316/178179)

Comment: Thank you @Franck for the pointer. But I also seen https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373075/2363712. There Felipe Hoffa claims _"you can use  Google BigQuery to query the quarterly dumps too"_ How did they get the "historical" version of the DB dumps? More about that here: https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/stack-exchange/stack-overflow?filter=solution-type:dataset&q=stackexchange&id=46a148ff-896d-444c-b08d-360169911f59

Comment: good point, no idea, in guessing private archives or archive.org

Comment: There is this [call to action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313799/158100) for community members and [this list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224873/all-stack-exchange-data-dumps/224922#224922)