Sites.xml is not present anymore in StackExchange data dumps
In recent changes more or less linked to Shifting the data dump schedule: A proposal, I notice that we do not have anymore the Sites.xml file in Stack Exchange data dumps.
The file was still present in https://archive.org/download/stackexchange but is missing since https://archive.org/download/stackexchange_20240630/stackexchange_20240630/, same in most recent https://archive.org/download/stackexchange_20240930/stackexchange_20240930/.
I've found https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1859893/sites-xml but it is a bit different (few columns missing, ...).
Am I missing something? Is this change intended or is it possible to resume providing Sites.xml together with the 7z archives? Is there a reliable alternative to get information from this file?
We are interested in Tagline, LongName, IconUrl and BadgeIconUrl, TotalTags, TotalQuestions, TotalUsers and TotalQuestions at least ; ideally having proper links to proper primary.css (e.g. https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/superuser/primary.css) and secondary.css (e.g. https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/superuser/secondary.css) would help as well, but this has always been missing from Sites.xml and guessing them based on IconUrl worked well so far.

I don't expect a sites.xml to be provided under the new data-dump process: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/401324/announcing-a-change-to-the-data-dump-process

Maybe helpful: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224873/all-stack-exchange-data-dump-releases

IconUrl is found in the response from https://data.stackexchange.com/sites

Thank you! Why don't you expect a Sites.xml to be provided under the new data-dump process? I'm sorry but nothing mentions this file in the mentioned questions (or I missed it many times), and it is said multiple times that nothing but the process will change.

You have to download the 7zip file now per site, on each site, from your user profile. There is no need or reason to have a sites.xml because there is no all-in-one option anymore offered by SE.

@rene that's an answer, which also explains why this should be marked [tag:status-bydesign]. (Or re-tagged to [tag:support].)

The problem is that the 7zip files do not contains information which was present in the Sites.xml. I don't mind if it is decided that this Sites.xml file will not be provided anymore "by-design", even if I find it a bit sad because it means we will have to guess most of the data I spoke about. Of course this data is useless for LLMs training, but our usage is far more "legitimate" than that and this information is important for us. And I'm concerned that AFAIK for now there is no real decision which has been published on this Sites.xml file, and all this look more or less accidental.
