# Download Stack Overflow dataset for college project

Tags: discussion, data-dump

I would like to download the Stack Overflow dataset that contains the *question title* and top-rated answer (not answer id).

Comment: Have you looked at SEDE (Stack Exchange Data Explorer)?  What have you tried?

Comment: I looked at Kaggle but found nothing

Comment: Maybe [start here](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial)

Comment: Also related: [All Stack Exchange data dumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224873).

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1412072

Comment: @SameerSingh, if you ***only*** want "the Question Title and top-rated answer" that is available by using a [search for highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer&searchOn=1).

Answer (score 3):

There's several 'versions' of the SE data dump floating around. You can find information on the [official data dumps here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19579/where-are-the-stack-exchange-data-dumps) and supposedly there's also a [google bigdata instance here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/public-datasets/google-bigquery-public-datasets-now-include-stack-overflow-q-a) - and [kaggle's instance seems to be from there](https://www.kaggle.com/stackoverflow/stackoverflow).

If you need an exact set of data, chances are you're going to have to query it yourself from one of those or SEDE.